# How to extract numbers from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, numbers

I would like to extract all the numbers contained in a string. Which is better suited for the purpose, regular expressions or the `isdigit()` method?

Example:

```
line = "hello 12 hi 89"
```

Result:

```
[12, 89]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the sample input data was so simplistic, since such invited naive solutions. Common cases should handle input strings with more interesting characters adjacent to the digits. A slightly more challenging input: `'''gimme digits from "12", 34, '56', -789.'''`

Answer (score 712, accepted):

If you only want to extract only positive integers, try the following:

```
>>> txt = "h3110 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog"
>>> [int(s) for s in txt.split() if s.isdigit()]
[23, 11, 2]
```

I would argue that this is better than the regex example because you don't need another module and it's more readable because you don't need to parse (and learn) the [regex mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

This will not recognize floats, negative integers, or integers in hexadecimal format.  If you can't accept these limitations, [jmnas's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-of-a-string/4289415#4289415) will do the trick.

Comment: I'm trying to extract numbers from a string representing coordinates (43°20'30"N) but some of them end in a decimal number (43°20'30.025"N) trying to figure out a way to pull out all numbers between any non-number but also recognizing that 30.025 is a number.

Comment: This won't detect 0 if it's the first number in the series.

Comment: @MrKingsley Is [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34429353/13642249) more helpful?

Comment: @kyrlon yes that is helpful thank you. I figured a less eloquent solution for the time being.

Answer (score 786):

I'd use a regexp:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', "hello 42 I'm a 32 string 30")
['42', '32', '30']
```

This would also match 42 from `bla42bla`. If you only want numbers delimited by word boundaries (space, period, comma), you can use \b:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', "he33llo 42 I'm a 32 string 30")
['42', '32', '30']
```

To end up with a list of numbers instead of a list of strings:

```
>>> [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', "he33llo 42 I'm a 32 string 30")]
[42, 32, 30]
```

NOTE: this does not work for negative integers

Comment: this doesn't work either for non integers `>>>temp='temp=46.7degrees`
`>>>re.findall(r'\d+',temp)` gives `['46','7']`. Use `re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+',temp)` for this particular case.

Answer (score 110):

You can extend the regular expression to account for scientific notation too.

```
import re

# Format is [(<string>, <expected output>), ...]
ss = [("apple-12.34 ba33na fanc-14.23e-2yapple+45e5+67.56E+3",
       ['-12.34', '33', '-14.23e-2', '+45e5', '+67.56E+3']),
      ('hello X42 I\'m a Y-32.35 string Z30',
       ['42', '-32.35', '30']),
      ('he33llo 42 I\'m a 32 string -30', 
       ['33', '42', '32', '-30']),
      ('h3110 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog', 
       ['3110', '23', '444.4', '11', '2']),
      ('hello 12 hi 89', 
       ['12', '89']),
      ('4', 
       ['4']),
      ('I like 74,600 commas not,500', 
       ['74,600', '500']),
      ('I like bad math 1+2=.001', 
       ['1', '+2', '.001'])]

for s, r in ss:
    rr = re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?", s)
    if rr == r:
        print('GOOD')
    else:
        print('WRONG', rr, 'should be', r)
```

Gives all good!

Additionally, you can look at the [AWS Glue built-in regex](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#classifier-builtin-patterns?icmpid=docs_glue_console)

Answer (score 104):

If you know it will be only one number in the string, i.e `'hello 12 hi'`, you can try `filter`.

For example, for non negative, whole numbers:

```
In [1]: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, '200 grams')))
Out[1]: 200
In [2]: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, 'Counters: 55')))
Out[2]: 55
In [3]: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, 'more than 23 times')))
Out[3]: 23
```

But be carefull !!! :

```
In [4]: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, '200 grams 5')))
Out[4]: 2005
```

Answer (score 87):

I'm assuming you want floats not just integers so I'd do something like this:

```
l = []
for t in s.split():
    try:
        l.append(float(t))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Note that some of the other solutions posted here don't work with negative numbers:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', 'he33llo 42 I\'m a 32 string -30')
['42', '32', '30']

>>> '-3'.isdigit()
False
```

Answer (score 41):

To catch different patterns it is helpful to query with different patterns.

### Setup all the patterns that catch different number patterns of interest:

- To find commas, e.g. 12,300 or 12,300.00

```
r'[\d]+[.,\d]+'
```

- To find floats, e.g. 0.123 or .123

```
r'[\d]*[.][\d]+'
```

- To find integers, e.g. 123

```
r'[\d]+'
```

### Combine with pipe ( `|` ) into one pattern with multiple *or conditionals*.

*(Note: Put complex patterns first else simple patterns will return chunks of the complex catch instead of the complex catch returning the full catch).*

```
p = '[\d]+[.,\d]+|[\d]*[.][\d]+|[\d]+'
```

Below, we'll confirm a pattern is present with `re.search()`, then return an iterable list of catches. Finally, we'll print each catch using bracket notation to subselect the match object return value from the match object.

```
s = 'he33llo 42 I\'m a 32 string 30 444.4 12,001'

if re.search(p, s) is not None:
    for catch in re.finditer(p, s):
        print(catch[0]) # catch is a match object
```

Returns:

```
33
42
32
30
444.4
12,001
```

Comment: This will also accept a number ending with a dot, like "30." You need something like that:  "[\d]+[\,\d]*[\.]{0,1}[\d]+"

Comment: what would you add for negative floats?

Answer (score 34):

I was looking for a solution to remove strings' masks, specifically from Brazilian phones numbers, this post not answered but inspired me. This is my solution:

```
>>> phone_number = '+55(11)8715-9877'
>>> ''.join([n for n in phone_number if n.isdigit()])
'551187159877'
```

Answer (score 25):

```
# extract numbers from garbage string:
s = '12//n,_@#$%3.14kjlw0xdadfackvj1.6e-19&*ghn334'
newstr = ''.join((ch if ch in '0123456789.-e' else ' ') for ch in s)
listOfNumbers = [float(i) for i in newstr.split()]
print(listOfNumbers)
[12.0, 3.14, 0.0, 1.6e-19, 334.0]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for posting an answer. It's always good practice to add some additional comments to your answer and why it solves the problem, rather than just posting a code snippet.

Comment: This makes problems if you have an input like `s = "Hello, world!"`, because the `e` cannot be floated alone. So you have to include an error handling like `try: float(i) except ValueError: ...`

Answer (score 23):

For phone numbers you can simply exclude all non-digit characters with `\D` in regex:

```py
import re

phone_number = "(619) 459-3635"
phone_number = re.sub(r"\D", "", phone_number)
print(phone_number)
```

The `r` in `r"\D"` stands for **raw string**. It is necessary. Without it, Python will consider `\D` as an escape character.

Answer (score 21):

Using Regex for non negative numbers below is the way

```
lines = "hello 12 hi 89"
import re
output = []
#repl_str = re.compile('\d+.?\d*')
repl_str = re.compile('^\d+$')
#t = r'\d+.?\d*'
line = lines.split()
for word in line:
        match = re.search(repl_str, word)
        if match:
            output.append(float(match.group()))
print (output)
```

with findall
`re.findall(r'\d+', "hello 12 hi 89")`

```
['12', '89']
```

`re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', "hello 12 hi 89 33F AC 777")`

```
['12', '89', '777']
```

Answer (score 13):

```
line2 = "hello 12 hi 89"  # this is the given string 
temp1 = re.findall(r'\d+', line2) # find number of digits through regular expression
res2 = list(map(int, temp1))
print(res2)
```

you can search all the integers in the string through digit by using findall expression.

In the second step create a list res2 and add the digits found in string to this list.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 10):

I am just adding this answer because no one added one using Exception handling and because this also works for floats

```
a = []
line = "abcd 1234 efgh 56.78 ij"
for word in line.split():
    try:
        a.append(float(word))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(a)
```

Output :

```
[1234.0, 56.78]
```

Answer (score 7):

This answer also contains the case when the number is float in the string

```
def get_first_nbr_from_str(input_str):
    '''
    :param input_str: strings that contains digit and words
    :return: the number extracted from the input_str
    demo:
    'ab324.23.123xyz': 324.23
    '.5abc44': 0.5
    '''
    if not input_str and not isinstance(input_str, str):
        return 0
    out_number = ''
    for ele in input_str:
        if (ele == '.' and '.' not in out_number) or ele.isdigit():
            out_number += ele
        elif out_number:
            break
    return float(out_number)
```

Answer (score 5):

I am amazed to see that no one has yet mentioned the usage of [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) as an alternative to achieve this.

You may use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) along with [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) in order to extract numbers from string as:

```
from itertools import groupby
my_str = "hello 12 hi 89"

l = [int(''.join(i)) for is_digit, i in groupby(my_str, str.isdigit) if is_digit]
```

The value hold by `l` will be:

```
[12, 89]
```

***PS:*** This is just for illustration purpose to show that as an alternative we could also use `groupby` to achieve this. But this is not a recommended solution. If you want to achieve this, you should be using [accepted answer of fmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289557/2063361) based on using list comprehension with `str.isdigit` as filter.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way i found:

```
>>> data = 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25'
>>> new_data = ''.join((ch if ch in '0123456789.-e' else ' ') for ch in data)
>>> numbers = [i for i in new_data.split()]
>>> print(numbers)
['122', '125', '55', '58', '25']
```

or this:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25'
>>> numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', data)
>>> print(numbers)
['122', '125', '55', '58', '25']
```

Comment: Both proposed solutions are not homogeneous. This regex one does : `re.findall(r'[\d.e-]+', data)`

Answer (score 2):

@jmnas, I liked your answer, but it didn't find floats.  I'm working on a script to parse code going to a CNC mill and needed to find both X and Y dimensions that can be integers or floats, so I adapted your code to the following.  This finds int, float with positive and negative vals.  Still doesn't find hex formatted values but you could add "x" and "A" through "F" to the `num_char` tuple and I think it would parse things like '0x23AC'.

```
s = 'hello X42 I\'m a Y-32.35 string Z30'
xy = ("X", "Y")
num_char = (".", "+", "-")

l = []

tokens = s.split()
for token in tokens:

    if token.startswith(xy):
        num = ""
        for char in token:
            # print(char)
            if char.isdigit() or (char in num_char):
                num = num + char

        try:
            l.append(float(num))
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since none of these dealt with real world financial numbers in excel and word docs that I needed to find, here is my variation. It handles ints, floats, negative numbers, currency numbers (because it doesn't reply on split), and has the option to drop the decimal part and just return ints, or return everything.

It also handles Indian Laks number system where commas appear irregularly, not every 3 numbers apart.

It does not handle scientific notation or negative numbers put inside parentheses in budgets -- will appear positive.

It also does not extract dates. There are better ways for finding dates in strings.

```
import re
def find_numbers(string, ints=True):            
    numexp = re.compile(r'[-]?\d[\d,]*[\.]?[\d{2}]*') #optional - in front
    numbers = numexp.findall(string)    
    numbers = [x.replace(',','') for x in numbers]
    if ints is True:
        return [int(x.replace(',','').split('.')[0]) for x in numbers]            
    else:
        return numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str1 = "There are 2 apples for 4 persons"

# printing original string 
print("The original string : " + str1) # The original string : There are 2 apples for 4 persons

# using List comprehension + isdigit() +split()
# getting numbers from string 
res = [int(i) for i in str1.split() if i.isdigit()]

print("The numbers list is : " + str(res)) # The numbers list is : [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

**The regex**

```
regx_pattern= r'\d+\.\d+|\d+'
```

**python implementation:**

```
import re

regx_pattern = r'\d+\.\d+|\d+'
txt = "The price is $12.99 and the quantity is 5 21321 dasdsa 123213."
matches = re.findall(regx_pattern, txt)
print(matches)
```

**Output:**

```
['12.99', '5', '21321', '123213']
```

**A little Explanation:**

It will spot digits '\d+' **OR** spot a digits with decimal points.
The python implementation finds all the matches and sets them in a list.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I found is below. It will extract a number and can eliminate any type of char.

```
def extract_nbr(input_str):
    if input_str is None or input_str == '':
        return 0

    out_number = ''
    for ele in input_str:
        if ele.isdigit():
            out_number += ele
    return float(out_number)
```

Comment: It's better to use join a list rather than += a string