# Can I remove all the letters from a string and keep just the numbers?

Tags: python, string

I'm working in python 2.6 and I would like to take "gpmetisfile.txt.part.4" and return just the number 4. (Ordinarily I would just lop off and save the end value, but its length and arrangement may change in the future and I would rather be safe and just obtain the numbers, in order, from the string itself).

There was a question similar to mine in 2009, but the answers were conflicting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/extract-numbers-of-a-string) by fmark.

Comment: @ryan, thanks! Sorry I missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does what your question answer says: removes everything but the numbers. Is that what you need?

```
In [1]: s = 'gpmetisfile.txt.part.4'

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.sub('\D', '', s)
Out[3]: '4'
```

The reason why I ask is that, for instance, `'gpmetisfile.txt.06_2012.part.4'` will become `'0620124'`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Only one number will appear in the string, ie now my file is "gpmetis.part.1205.txt". Thank you for checking.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = 'as!das42!fsd'
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s))
'42'
```

Comment: Great! this also works. Is there a benefit of using one method over another?

Comment: @AllysonKim, this solution is two times faster than regex :) Regular expressions are good for complex text processing, but are overkill in this case, IMHO

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could select both answers.