# Python : extract data from some nasty html

Tags: python, html, parsing, text-extraction

My question is related to usage of [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) but on a bit of nast html code.
I have a file/webpage containing multiple html/css entries and somewhere in bewteen the lines i get this frequently repeated parts of html code i need to parse to extract some certain data.


**For example:**

1)
Number 66 to be extracted
Number 123456 to be extracted ftom this comment

```
<h3 class="s KB8NC">66.&hsbc; 
<!--
        <A name="simp123456" href="text.php?p=1&i_simp_z_boc_nb_sec=123456&i_simp_s_vitrazka=1">
-->
ristill advocka, sygint: SURVE/123-021/11-2/XX</h3>
```

And another frequent entries which show up in pairs:

2)
First entry to be **ignored** because of empty 'data'
Number **123456** to extract

```
<p class="monozzio"></p>
<p class="monozzio"><a href="text.php?p=1&pup;i_simp_z_boc_nb_sec=123456&pup;i_simp_s_vitrazka=1">monozzio...</a></p>
```

Here is my first class so far but it starts to exceed my skills, any help appreciated.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
class MyParser(HTMLParser):  
   def __init__(self):
HTMLParser.__init__(self)
self.recording = 0
self.data = []
   def handle_starttag(self, tag, attributes):
     if tag != 'p':
       return
     if self.recording:
       self.recording += 1
       return
     for name, value in attributes:
     if name == 'class' and value == 'monozzio':
        break
     else:
     return
     self.recording = 1

def handle_endtag(self, tag):
  if tag == 'p' and self.recording:
    self.recording -= 1

def handle_data(self, data):
  if self.recording:
    ##############################
    #here parse data to get 123456
    ##############################
  self.data.append(data)

p = MyParser()
f = open('file.html', 'r')
htm = f.read()
p.feed(htm)
print '\n'.join(p.data)
p.close()
```

Comment: Do you want to extract ALL the integers from your html? You could refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/extract-numbers-of-a-string

Comment: I want to extract just those integers from my example - for whole html, i mean structure of this tags is repeating and numers are changing but still they are in the same plce among tag.

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly a solution to your problem, but [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a library that makes it easier to parse HTML.

Then you can do something like:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup(your_html_content)
for link in html.find_all('p.monozzio a'):  # use css selectors
    href = link.get('href')
    reg = re.compile('i_simp_z_boc_nb_sec=([0-9]+)')
    nbrs = reg.findall(href)  # regex to extract values
```

Note that I didn't test the code, it's just a general idea.