# Filtering text in python for numeric values

Tags: python, regex

I know I could use regular expressions to filter text in python for digits, but is that the best way?

Say I have a list of strings:

```
a="gamma function: 78"
b="factorial value: 120"
c="random number: 33"
```

is there a good function that would do the following?

```
for string in [a,b,c]:
    return numbers(string)
78
120
33
```

Comment: best here is meaning 1) easiest, and 2) fastest (computationally), in that order.

Comment: Is there always just one number per string? Is it always an integer?

Comment: ideally yes to both. i will accept an answer that assumes that.

Comment: also is it always at the end of the string, following ": "?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/extract-numbers-of-a-string

Comment: semi-related: having an unconditional `return` in a for loop probably won't give you what you want. Ex. `for i in range(3): return i` will return `0`, not `[0,1,2]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I'd say regexes are the ideal tool for this:

```
def numbers(s):
    return int(re.search(r"\d+", s).group(0))
```

For strings with more than one number:

```
def numbers(s):
    return [int(match) for match in re.findall(r"\d+", s)]
```

or even

```
def numbers(s):
    return (int(match) for match in re.finditer(r"\d+", s))
```

If you want to join all the digits in your string into a single number:

```
def numbers(s):
    return int("".join(re.findall(r"\d+", s)))

>>> numbers("abc78def90ghi")
7890
```

Comment: A `map` seems in order here: `map(int, re.findall("\d+", s)`. But +1, just what I would do :)

Comment: What if the string is like this `78abc98`. Is it possible we can filter out `7898` in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the non-digits in a generator-expression:

```
a="gamma function: 78"
b="factorial value: 120"
c="random number: 33"

numbers = []
for string in [a,b,c,]:
    numbers.append( int("".join(char for char in string if char.isdigit())))
```

Pasting this on the console, I got:

```
>>> numbers
[78, 120, 33]
```

Comment: This is good for one number in each string, even if the digits are sparsed by other chars. Please clarify your question if there are cases in which there may be more than one number in each string - oh, i saw that yes, in your comments now.