# Best way to clean up the unmatched records given by REGEX (Alphanumeric) using python?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, python-re, alphanumeric

I have a dataset where there are column with alphanumeric values. I am able to filter the unmatched records now I want to clean them, that means for example the unmatched record is `123*abc&` then it should remove `123abc`. I have done it but I don't think this is a correct way to do it and also the data is combined after the final results I can use for loop for getting them correctly but that will be a slow process. Hence looking for a easier way (column by column cleaning). Is it possible to do so?

```
data = ['abc123','abc*123&','Abc123','ABC@*&123',np.nan,'123*Abc']
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a'])
print(df)
       a
0     abc123
1   abc*123&
2     Abc123
3  ABC@*&123
4        NaN
5    123*Abc
```

Filtering unmatched records:

```
wrong=df[~df['a'].str.contains(numeric, na=True)]
print(wrong)
        a
1   abc*123&
3  ABC@*&123
5    123*Abc


wrong_index = wrong.index
result = ''.join(i for i in wrong['a'] if not i.isalpha())  
alphanumeric = [character for character in result if character.isalnum()]
alphanumeric = "".join(alphanumeric)
df['a'].loc[wrong_index]=alphanumeric
print(df)
     a
0   abc123
1   abc123ABC123123Abc
2   Abc123
3   abc123ABC123123Abc
4   NaN
5   abc123ABC123123Abc
```

I know why is this happening, can be resolved by using for or loop through each row but it consumes a lot of time. Is there any way where we can do column by column clean up?

Excepted output:

```
       a
0     abc123
1     abc123
2     Abc123
3     ABC123
4        NaN
5     123Abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain vanilla Python using the built-in Regex module `re` will do.
See this [demo on IDEone: using regular-expression to replace list elements](https://ideone.com/LE6Nmu)

```py
import re

data = ['abc123','abc*123&','Abc123','ABC@*&123','123*Abc']
cleaned = [re.sub('\W', '', item) for item in data]
print(cleaned)
```

The script will output:

> ['abc123', 'abc123', 'Abc123', 'ABC123', '123Abc']

#### Explained

1. The `re.sub` function substitutes a given string (here: `item`) like
   search & replace.
2. The *search* is specified by regular-expression:
   `\W` all non-word characters (i.e. non numerical digits, non alpha
   letters).
3. The *replace* is specified by an empty string to simply
   remove the found: `''`.
4. The **for-loop** is implemented as
   [list-comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python),
   a ideomatic or *pythonic* way for iterating through elements of a
   list.

### Filter parts of above

If you like to filter to only parts, like only alphabetic or only numeric chars, then you need to combine *metacharacters* of PCRE like in this [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/9mc5sH):

```py
import re

data = ['abc123','abc*123&','Abc123','ABC@*&123','123*Abc', '123_abc', '123 abc']

# replace non-alphas and non-digits; filter [A-Za-z0-9_]
alphanumeric_underscore = [re.sub('\W', '', item) for item in data]
print('alphanumeric_underscore', alphanumeric_underscore)

# replace also the underscore; filter [A-Za-z0-9]
alphanumeric = [re.sub('[\W_]', '', item) for item in data]
print('alphanumeric', alphanumeric)

# filter only digits
numeric = [re.search(r"\d+", item).group(0) for item in data]
print('numeric', numeric)

# filter only alphas
alpha = [re.search(r"[A-Za-z]+", item).group(0) for item in data]
print('alpha', alpha)
```

It will output:

> alphanumeric_underscore ['abc123', 'abc123', 'Abc123', 'ABC123', '123Abc', '123_abc', '123abc']
> alphanumeric ['abc123', 'abc123', 'Abc123', 'ABC123', '123Abc', '123abc', '123abc']
> numeric ['123', '123', '123', '123', '123', '123', '123']
> alpha ['abc', 'abc', 'Abc', 'ABC', 'Abc', 'abc', 'abc']

It uses the regex-search `re.search` with regex (prefixed as raw-string) `r"\d+"` to return all found occurrences `.group(0)`, hence filter.

### See also

- official Python 3 documentation: [re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- official Python 3 documentation: [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)
- similar SO answer: [Filtering text in python for numeric values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886363/ddg#13886423)
- interesting SO question about *raw-string*: [Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix)

Comment: Out of a doubt. In the same scenario, how do we remove integers

Comment: @Pysdm @Pysdm Whithout punctuation, I understand this as "rhetoric" question.  Integers can be equally removed by _substituting_ the regex for _digits_ [`\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/ZbNITh/1) or the opposite: filtering using regex search for [any non-digits](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/Perl-Compatible_Regular_Expressions), using the matching _PCRE metachar_ (it's analogue to `\w` matching _word-chars_ negated to `\W` .. so `\d` becomes ❔).

Comment: Sorry, that's a digit but when I am trying to remove both integers and special character  it isn't working. When I gave just r'\d+' it is removing integers and for removing alphabets r'[a-zA-Z]+' but when I want to remove for int,spcl char it is not removing. I gave a pattern r'[$&+,:;=?@#|<>.^*()%!-][\d+]' it's removing

Comment: I got it. ([^\d]+?)' for removing integers and ([^a-zA-z]+?)' for alphabets

Comment: @Pysdm You got it ️ Even simpler, without parentheses/capture-group `()`, negation-operator `^` or greedy-[quantifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) `?`. For example to __keep only the special-chars__ can be turned into "remove [digits and alphas](https://regex101.com/r/ubX4jW/1)" by `re.sub('[A-Za-z\d]', '', s)`.