# Operate on all matches of Python's re.split / similar builtin on a single pass

Tags: python, regex

If I've a string like, `'level1-4car10'`, I want to extract all those numbers (integers, specifically) as numbers, in a list.

When I run,

```
re.split(r'(\d+)', 'level1-4car10')
```

That does half the job, giving me a result of,

```
['level', '1', '-', '4', 'car', '10', '']
```

But what I'm looking for is,

```
['level', 1, '-', 4, 'car', 10, '']
```

The 1, 4 and 10 are real integers now, not numbers.  Currently, using `re.split` with capturing, I'll have to run through the returned list to do that, and I'm just wondering if there's any other option available to me to do this in a more one-pass way, like the `key` section of `sorted`.

edit: I've reworded the question, specifically stating `single pass`.

This is also different to the answer regarding [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string) as I don't just want the numbers, I want the numbers and the `not number` in a list ordered by how they appear in the sentence.

Comment: *I want to **extract** all those numbers* why use re.split then? now you're just splitting the string on numbers

Comment: I found that was the easiest way to split the string and end up with what closest to what I wanted first pass.  I'm more than happy to be corrected and pointed away from `re.split`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: Are you still expecting other answers?..because I see you didn't select the accepted one.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, the title is operating on all outputs from the re.split, not just extracting the ints, that's a separate issue.  I want, if possible, a mixed type list returned, not a list of strings, not a list *just* of the ints, as I said like, `['level', 1, '-', 4, 'car', 10, '']`.  I've also already clarified why it's different to the other answer, and that I'm looking for a single pass.  All the answers are two pass, which isn't what I'm asking about.  I don't think it's actually possible, but that shouldn't mean I accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use map

```
map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x, re.split(r'(\d+)', 'level1-4car10'))
```

Comment: I know map alright, but (I have now edited the title to specify this) this, unless I'm mistaken is two pass.  There are a million and one options to that, what I'm specifically looking to do is a one-pass solution.  Operate on the items as they're matched, instead of operating on the returned list.

Answer (score 2):

```
[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in re.split(r'(\d+)', 'level1-4car10')]
```

Comment: Wrong , type(string) == 'str' is always false

Comment: This is two pass, if possible, I'm looking for a one pass solution, where the items are operated on as they're matched, rather than the whole returned list.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about any one pass way, but you can use `list comprehension` to acheieve this in one line , example -

```
newlist = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in re.split(r'(\d+)', 'level1-4car10') if x != '']
>>> newlist
['level', 1, '-', 4, 'car', 10]
```

If you want to keep the empty string as well -

```
newlist = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in re.split(r'(\d+)', 'level1-4car10')]
>>> newlist
['level', 1, '-', 4, 'car', 10, '']
```

Comment: Just an fyi, as with the other lines, while this is one-line, I've removed that from my question as that wasn't the important part, the important part was *one-pass*, which is why I haven't accepted any answer as correct.  All are currently two-pass solutions.