# Extracting Numbers from a String Without Regular Expressions

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to extract all the numbers from a string composed of digits, symbols and letters.
If the numbers are multi-digit, I have to extract them as multidigit (e.g. from `"shsgd89shs2011%%5swts"`), I have to pull the numbers out as they appear (`89`, `2011` and `5`).
So far what I have done just loops through and returns all the numbers incrementally, which I like but I cannot figure out how to make it stop
after finishing with one set of digits:

```
    def StringThings(strng):
         nums = []
         number = ""
         for each in range(len(strng)):
             if strng[each].isdigit():
                 number += strng[each]
             else:
                 continue
            nums.append(number)

        return nums
```

Running this value: `"6wtwyw66hgsgs"` returns `['6', '66', '666']`
w
hat simple way is there of breaking out of the loop once I have gotten what I needed?

Comment: You could try use the answers to a similar question in [python extract numbers from a string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  But it doesn't work for all cases too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to account for trailing numbers:

```
def StringThings(strng):
    nums = []
    number = ""
    for each in range(len(strng)):
        if strng[each].isdigit():
            number += strng[each]

        if each == len(strng)-1:
            if number != '':
                nums.append(number)

        if each != 0:
            if strng[each].isdigit() == False:
                 if strng[each-1].isdigit():
                     nums.append(number)
                     number = "" 
                     continue;
    return nums

print StringThings("shsgd89shs2011%%5swts34");
// returns ['89', '2011', '5', '34']
```

So, when we reach a character which is not a number, and if the previously observed character was a number, append the contents of `number` to `nums` and then simply empty our temporary container `number`, to avoid it containing all the old stuff.

Note, I don't know Python so the solution may not be very pythonic.

Alternatively, save yourself all the work and just do:

```
import re
print re.findall(r'\d+', 'shsgd89shs2011%%5swts');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not allowed to use re, and I have tried this before, and it doesn't work in all cases. For instance "67gobbledegook95" returns '67'.

Answer (score 1):

Using your function, just use a temp  variable to concat each sequence of digits, yielding the groups each time you encounter a non-digit if the temp variable is not an empty string:

```
def string_things(strng):
    temp = ""
    for ele in strng:
        if ele.isdigit():
            temp += ele
        elif temp: # if we have a sequence
            yield temp
            temp = "" # reset temp
    if temp: # catch ending sequence
        yield temp
```

Output

```
In [9]: s = "shsgd89shs2011%%5swts"
In [10]: list(string_things(s))
Out[10]: ['89', '2011', '5']

In [11]: s ="67gobbledegook95"
In [12]: list(string_things(s))
Out[12]: ['67', '95']
```

Or you could translate the string replacing letters and punctuation with spaces then split:

```
from string import ascii_letters, punctuation, maketrans
s = "shsgd89shs2011%%5swts"

replace = ascii_letters+punctuation

tbl = maketrans(replace," " * len(replace))
print(s.translate(tbl).split())
['89', '2011', '5']
```

Comment: Wow. Another great solution. I feel dumber by the minute. First time running into "yield". Thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
L2 = []
file_Name1 = 'shsgd89shs2011%%5swts' 
from itertools import groupby
for k,g in groupby(file_Name1, str.isdigit):
    a = list(g)
    if k == 1:
        L2.append("".join(a))
```

print(L2)

Result ['89', '2011', '5']

Comment: Thanks! But I am not allowed to use any modules, at all.

Comment: @Sina `I am not allowed to use any modules` Where you wrote about this??? Please, for the future,  write all special conditions in question (first post) in order to people don't waste your time. I was whole hour finding answer for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, Oleg. But I did say in the title no regular expressions. I suppose that was insufficient information. Thanks for your help,  it's still very valuable information for me.

Comment: @Sina Where you see "regular expressions" in my code???? I use "groupby" from "itertools" library.

Comment: @Sina   On the contrary, I was finding solution without using of regex library. where you see `import re` in the represented excerpt of code???