# How to seperate numbers from strings?

Tags: python, string

I want to separate numbers and other characters in a string which is entered by user.

example:

```
str = insert 0 9
```

I want to store "insert" in another variable and 0,9 in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: Have you tried running your example in Python?

Comment: please post question clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'insert 0 9'
li= s.split(' ')
var = li[0]
del li[0]

print(var)
insert

print(li)

['0', '9']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "insert 0 9"
args = str.split()
cmd = args.pop(0)
args = map(int, args)

cmd
# => "insert"
args
# => [0, 9]
```

Of course, maybe I misunderstood the question, so it might not fit.

Answer (score 0):

if the use `rawinput` to have input from console, you cannot separate string from numbers. what you can do is to get your input as a string, split it with `string.split()` and analyze the resulting element to see if his components are numbers or letters, with some `if`.

Comment: Well, `raw_input()` has been instead with `input()` on Python 3.