# Replacing characters in string by whitespace except digits

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all the characters and special symbols from a string in python except the numbers(digits 0-9). This is what I am doing-

```
s='das dad 67 8 - 11 2928  313'
s1=''
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    if not(ord(s[i])>=48 and ord(s[i])<=57):
        s1=s1+' '
    else:
        s1=s1+s[i]  
#s1=s1.split()      
print(s1)
```

So, basically I am checking the ascii codes for each character, if they do not lie in the range of digits' ascii values, I update them by whitespace. This works fine, but I was curious if there is some other more efficient way I can do this in python.

**Edit** I want to replace non-digit characters with whitespace

Comment: I hope you understand that by doing this, if your string has any floats, they will be discarded.

Comment: Oh thanks, I missed that. Yes I do not want that

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How can I keep the float values also?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid floats will be saved now..check edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import re
s1=re.sub(r"[^0-9 ]"," ",s)
```

You can use `re` here.

To prevent `.` of floating numbers use

```
(?!(?<=\d)\.(?=\d))[^0-9 ]
```

Comment: Is there some way to keep floats values also?

Comment: Can I also include `.` alongwith `0-9` so that float values are not removed?

Comment: @Joker yes you can gimme a min

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a regular expression, you could simply use a list comprehension:

```
>>> s='das dad 67 8 - 11 2928  313'
>>> ''.join([c if c.isdigit() else ' ' for c in s])
'        67 8   11 2928  313'
```

Comment: you don't need the inner list.

Comment: @DSM +1 for a different approach. but I believe regular expression is more efficient.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: `''.join` is one of the rare cases where using a listcomp can be more effective than a genexp, because you have to materialize the list *anyway* before `''.join` can do its thing.  Raymond Hettinger has a post here somewhere on the subject which I'm too lazy to look up right now..

Comment: This was perfect for when I needed to extract the numbers in a string, but not merge all digits together!

Answer (score 1):

python re, regular expression module has lot of helpful methods to match pattern in the string. Use re.sub method to substitute regular expression pattern in the string

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string)
>
> "Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost\n
>   non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the\n
>   replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;\n    if
>   a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is\n    a
>   callable, it's passed the match object and must return\n    a
>   replacement string to be used."

```
>>> string = "das dad 67 8 - 11 2928  313"
>>> re.sub('[^0-9]',' ', string)
'        67 8   11 2928  313'
```

*re.sub arguments*

1. `[^0-9]` - Match every character other than 0-9 digits
2. `' '`    -  replace with space
3. `string` - original string

Comment: Can I also include . alongwith 0-9 so that float values are not removed?