# Find PinCode in file of various letters/numbers

Tags: python, for-loop

***Given a file of seemingly meaningless letters called “data.txt”, write a function findPin(inFile) that returns a four-number pin code within file. (All other characters are letters except for the pin code)***

I know I'm supposed to open the data file and then iterate through it until I come across a number, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  The data.txt file is...

```
loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelit
seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremag
naaliquautenimadminimveniamquisnostrudexercitat
ionullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconseq
uatduisauteiruredolorinrepre7269henderitinvolup
tatevelitessecillumdoloreeufugiatnullapariature
xcepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproidentsuntinc
ulpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborumqwe
```

So obviously the pin number is 7269, but I need helping getting there.  Sorry I'm just a beginner in python and this is really tripping me up.

Comment: you should use isdecimal() string method

Comment: regex is the best method I believe

Comment: I have to point out though that is it a bit worrying that you are writing a function `findPin()` to extract a 4-digit PIN from an unknown and scrambled text-format... Whilst the solution for this is pretty easily obtainable it does beg to ask: *What are you actually doing here!?* - some more details given the possible context might be a good idea in future posts

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderMcFarlane's dup target but note that most of the answers on it assume that the number is separated to the other words by spaces, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4289348/5827215) does show a version for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`,

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    pin_code = ''.join([filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), line) for line in f])

print(pin_code)
# Output
7269
```

---

Or use `re.sub`,

```
import re

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    pin_code = ''.join([re.sub("\D", "", line) for line in f])

print(pin_code)
# Output
7269
```

Answer (score 0):

[`regex`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOg4SYo9LMAhXlDMAKHYDrBKMQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2Fre.html&usg=AFQjCNG39_RKNnDcP0dmnM-N6OPINFho0g&sig2=tAYczcMi9ezB0jhzEa9R8A) is a more robust method than looping as providing different string formats can cause the loop to fail.

```
string = """loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelit
seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremag
naaliquautenimadminimveniamquisnostrudexercitat
ionullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconseq
uatduisauteiruredolorinrepre7269henderitinvolup
tatevelitessecillumdoloreeufugiatnullapariature
xcepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproidentsuntinc
ulpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborumqwe"""
```

This is using `regex`

```
import re
results = re.findall(r"\d+", string)
```

This provides a list of each digit instance which can be merged by: `merged  = "".join(result)`

Here is a [link](http://regexone.com/references/python) to a site that demonstrates some common uses of `regex` pattern matching for your future use.

Few people remember `regex` patterns but most programmers will know when to use them and know how to search for the correct pattern quickly.

Comment: For a comprehensive set of solutions see the link provided on your original post.

Answer (score -3):

```
a = 'abc1234def'
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i].isdigit():
        print a[i:i+4]
```

Updated with hints from comments.

Comment: Actually this really does not work, at all.

Comment: good attempt, although you need `a[i].isdigit()` for it to work correctly and `a[i:i+4]` to correctly use slicing (what you have works fine but I'd recommend doing the slice in one step if you can)

Comment: I just now realized, that this is stupid. It will print '1234' as well as '234d', '34de' and '4def'.