# How to extract the first numbers in a string - Python

Tags: python, string, numbers, truncate

How do I remove all the numbers before the first letter in a string? For example,

```
myString = "32cl2"
```

I want it to become:

```
"cl2"
```

I need it to work for any length of number, so 2h2 should become h2, 4563nh3 becomes nh3 etc. 
**EDIT:**
This has numbers without spaces between so it is not the same as the other question and it is specifically the first numbers, not all of the numbers.

Comment: At the risk of sounding snarky, I'd say you should try writing a function in python to take care of this. For starters, you can iterate over a string and to test whether each character is a number or not.. `for char in myString:` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Extract numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to solve it without regular expressions, you could have used [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>>
>>> ''.join(dropwhile(str.isdigit, "32cl2"))
'cl2'
>>> ''.join(dropwhile(str.isdigit, "4563nh3"))
'nh3'
```

---

Or, using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), replacing one or more digits at the beginning of a string:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"^\d+", "", "32cl2")
'cl2'
>>> re.sub(r"^\d+", "", "4563nh3")
'nh3'
```

Comment: Cheers mate, would give you a thumbs up but I can't!

Answer (score 2):

Use `lstrip`:

```
myString.lstrip('0123456789')
```

or

```
import string
myString.lstrip(string.digits)
```

Comment: I like this better than the chosen answer because it is simpler.