# Pattern matching with regex returns None while it should not

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, match

I am learning regex and Beautiful Soup and I am doing the Google Tutorial on Regex.  I am using the HTML files provided in the Google Tutorial website (exercise set in the set up section of the tutorial)

The code is the following:

```
with open(filepath,"r") as f: soup = bs(f, 'lxml')
soup.title
```

out

```
<title>Popular Baby Names</title>
```

code:

```
h3 = soup.find_all("h3") # With find_all() I will capture the content of the <h3> Tags (In fact only one h3 Tag exists
                         # containing the Year)

h3[0].get_text()
```

out

```
u'Popularity in 1990'
```

code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'.+(\d\d\d\d).+') 
string = h3[0].get_text()
pattern.match(string).group(0)
```

out

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-2e4daef3292c> in <module>()
----> 1 pattern.match(string).group(0)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I can not explain why match() does not capture the year as it should.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your string ends with `1990`, so the later `.+` can't match anything.

Comment: As other comments have stated, your regex doesn't work - you can test here: https://regex101.com/r/d2NjKz/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Extract numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: Thank you. The problem was the .+ in the end.  When I deleted it worked.  However, I had tested it on regex101 but instead of passing the text only, I had passed the tags as well so it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Because it expects at least one character after the year. Try .* instead of .+

Comment: Why does it need to match `.*`?

Comment: `*` matches zero or more of the former character, so no more characters are required to get a match.

Comment: it doesn't, I'm assuming he did .+ because he might want something after the year, but + requires at least one character. zero or more is *.

Comment: @palako But it isn't used to match anything.