# How to find a pair of numbers between parentheses using a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string with some text / numbers in it. There is always a `()` with two numbers in between. These two numbers need to be extracted.
The string looks like this:

```
s = 'sadfdaf dsf4as d a4d34s ddfd (54.4433,-112.3554) a45 6sd 6f8 asdf'
```

I need a regular expression for solving that. 
Pseudo code like this

1. search `s` for `(` and check if number is next char
2. Extract numbers until `,`
3. Extract second number until `)`

I found the following solution from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

```
print re.findall("[-+]?\d+[\.]?\d*[eE]?[-+]?\d*", schoolAddressString)
```

which returns: `['4', '4', '34', '54.4433', '-112.3554', '45', '6', '6', '8']`

So I need to have this expression to only consider numbers between `()` with something like`^(` and `$(`.

How is this done exactly?

Comment: `\((yourpattern),(yourpattern)\)` seems quite accurate to me.

Comment: The found pattern matches exponential format. If your data source does not use this, anything starting from *[eE]...* may be left out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use a *regex* to **capture the elements between brackets**, and then parse these using `.split(',')` and `float` to parse them to floats. Like:

```
for match in re.findall(r'(?<=\().*?(?=\))',schoolAddressString):
    a,b = map(float,match.split(','))
    # do something with a and b, for example
    print([a,b])
```

This prints:

```
>>> for match in re.findall(r'(?<=\().*?(?=\))',schoolAddressString):
...     a,b = map(float,match.split(','))
...     # do something with a and b, for example
...     print([a,b])
... 
[54.4433, -112.3554]
```

Furthermore here you parse a `float`. Therefore I think that the parsing will be *less* error prone: there will be more patterns that *can* be parsed, and the parsing is probably done correctly.

The result of the `map(..)` is a list. So in case there can be an *arbitrary* number of values between the brackets, you can use `values = map(..)` and then process the elements in `values`.

## Float pattern

The pattern the `float(..)` constructor can parse is described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float):

> ```
> sign           ::=  "+" | "-"
> infinity       ::=  "Infinity" | "inf"
> nan            ::=  "nan"
> numeric_value  ::=  floatnumber | infinity | nan
> numeric_string ::=  [sign] numeric_value
>
> floatnumber     ::=  pointfloat | exponentfloat
> pointfloat      ::=  [digitpart] fraction | digitpart "."
> exponentfloat   ::=  (digitpart | pointfloat) exponent
> digitpart       ::=  digit (["_"] digit)*
> fraction        ::=  "." digitpart
> exponent        ::=  ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digitpart
>
> digit           ::=  "0"..."9"
> ```

So the "added" value of using the constructor is that underscores are allowed as well (to separate *groups* of digits), and furthermore values like `infinity`, `inf` and `nan` are also allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
for segment in re.findall("[(][^)]*[)]", s):
    print re.findall("[-+]?\d+[\.]?\d*[eE]?[-+]?\d*", segment)
```

Note that this works no matter how many numbers are in each segment, or how they are separated, which is more flexible than it sounds like you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you're variable s is a string you can use the split method ([docs python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split))
You can make a code like that :

```
s = 'sadfdaf dsf4as d a4d34s ddfd (54.4433,-112.3554) a45 6sd 6f8 asdf'
s_without_beginning = s.split('(')[1]
s_without_extremeties = s_without_beginning.split(')')[0]
numbers = s_without_extremeties.split(',')
```

This will return :

numbers =

```
['54.4433', '-112.3554']
```

But you have to be sure the separators are always ( , )