# Split by comma, newline, and carriage return

Tags: python-2.7

I want to read an input file that has the format:

> ['1,2,3\r\n', '4,5,6']

I want them to be separated so it will look like

> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

My code looks like

```
def importFile(file):
with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    print content
    for line in content:
        tempList = line.split(',')
    print tempList
```

Unfortunately, what I'm getting right now is

> ['4', '5', '6']

Where did I do wrong? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're overwriting the contents of `tempList` inside that `for` loop so you only have the contents from the last iteration.

Comment: @mrogers I made some minor changes, but now I'm getting `[['1,2,3\r\n'], ['4,5,6']]`. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate my comment: the issue is that you're overwriting `tempList` at each iteration of the `for` loop (each line of your file).  Below is one way you could solve the issue.  I borrowed the regex to pull digits out of your lines to get rid of the `\r\n` from [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string).
The core of this solution is that second `for` loop that iterates over the contents of each line.

```
import re

def importFile(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        print content
        result = []
        for line in content:
            tempList = line.split(',')
            for x in tempList:
                result.append(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0])
        print result
```

Comment: I see, so it turns out I just need a place to store the split result directly. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure you could get more creative with other solutions.  This is just the first one that came to mind.