# Using regex to get numbers from a string using Python, incorrectly prints full string

Tags: python, regex, selenium

## Objective

- I'm looking to use the regular expression `\d+` to extract just the digits from the string, `answer_40194`.

## Problem

- I'm targeting a form element with Selenium and I'm printing the formID to the Terminal, but after the line `re.findall('\d+', formID)` I expect `formID` to be just the numbers `40194`, but instead I'm getting the entire string `answer_40194`.

## script.py

```
import selenium
import re

form = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
formID = form.get_attribute('id')
re.findall('\d+', formID)
print formIDNumber
```

Comment: You haven't assigned the result of the regex match to anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result to a variable, e.g.

```
var1 = re.findall('\d+', formID)
print(var1)
```

This will generate a list, if you only want one result, use

```
var1 = re.search('\d+', formID)
print(var1.group(0))
```

The latter is called a **regular expression object**, hence the `.group(0)`, see the [**documentation on python.org**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information.

Comment: Just tried the snippet you posted as a solution, running into a similar problem. Getting `'list' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @MaryYacoubian: You're certainly mixing the two alternatives.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct.