# How to convert string to number in python

Tags: python

I have a column in a dataframe named 'term'. its value is ('36 months', '60 months', '36 months', '36 months', '60 months')
Now I want to convert that column to numeric like (36,60,36,36,60)
How can I do that?

Comment: Lack of effort, because it takes fewer keystrokes for a google search than to log in and type a question here.

Comment: `(36,60,36,36,60)` is not a numeric dtype, it would still be `object`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem love that show!

Comment: `a.something = a.something.apply(lambda x: x.strip(' months')).astype(np.int64)`. I tested it, it works. Probably quite obscure though and intentionally so; please show some effort on your part.

Comment: Here's a helpful reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
In [12]: df 
Out[12]: 
        term
0  36 months
1  60 months
2  36 months
3  36 months
4  60 months

In [14]: df.term.str.replace(' months','').astype(int)
Out[14]: 
0    36
1    60
2    36
3    36
4    60
Name: term, dtype: int64
```