# read only numbers from text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file with the following entries:

```
 Y-6.352 Z281.116 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0
```

I want only the numbers of each variable as follows:

```
 -6.352 281.116 -1.0 0.0 0.0
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this? I am new to python and couldn't figure a function to work this out. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

So if your text file contains:

```
Y-6.352 Z281.116 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0
Y-6.352 Z281.116 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 Y2.249 Z283.923 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0
```

You could use the following non-regex approach:

```
def get_value(v):
    try:
        return float(v.split('=')[1])
    except IndexError as e:
        return float(v[1:])

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for raw_row in f_input:
        values = map(get_value, raw_row.split())
        print values
```

Giving you:

```
[-6.352, 281.116, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-6.352, 281.116, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.249, 283.923, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Unfortunately all the lines are not similar. They are something like this :    `Y-6.352 Z281.116 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0`  `Y2.249 Z283.923 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0`

Comment: Then best use a function. I have updated the script.

Answer (score 0):

Say `s` is the line of your file, you can use lookbehind assertion. `?<=` to check for variables!

```
>>> import re
>>> s
'Y-6.352 Z281.116 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0'
>>> re.findall("(?<=[AZaz])?(?!\d*=)[0-9.+-]+",s)
['-6.352', '281.116', '-1.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

If you want to do the same with files,

```
import re
with open('input file.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print re.findall("(?<=[AZaz])?(?!\d*=)[0-9.+-]+",line)
```

Comment: missed the first digit

Comment: Variables are not differentiated with `=`! I just realised. Give me a moment!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran it works partially though. My input line is just a set of values but you have taken it as a string ' '. I have a whole file with 100+ input lines like these. How to take them as a string?

Comment: This works too! >>> s='Y-342.33'
>>> re.findall("(?<=[AZaz])?[0-9.+-]+",s)
['-342.33']

Comment: When you read the lines of your file, it is read as string and hence that shouldn't be a problem. Can you please share a sample IO!

Comment: input:  `Y-6.352 Z281.116 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0`  `Y2.249 Z283.923 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0`  output:  `-6.352, 281.116, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0`   `2.249, 283.923, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0`

Comment: Okay! The second code snippet does just this! It reads through the lines of file and finds the patters!

Comment: Cool. If you feel if a solution answers your question, kindly accept it so that it can help someone else with a similar problem!