# pull numbers and letters together python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am looking to delete any text from a string in python that matches something along the lines of "\nPage 10 of 12\n" where 10 and 12 are always different numbers (looping through 300+ documents that all have different page lengths). Example of some text that is in my string below (and then what i would want the output to be):

```
thisisaboutthen\n\n\nPage 2 of 12\n\nnowwearegoing\n\nPage 3 of 12\n\n\n\

Output -> thisisaboutthennnowwearegoing
```

I am trying the code:

```
page = r'\nPage \b\d+\b of \b\d+\b\n+'
return re.sub(page, '', string)
```

But I can't get it to work. I tried to refer to this link [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string) for help but I can't seem to combine numbers and letters together.

I'm new to regex in python and any help would be great. I have been able to get regex to work when it is just letters or just numbers, but running into problems when combining them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: All you need is a `+` before `Page`: `\n+Page \b\d+\b of \b\d+\b\n+`

Comment: Your pattern looks good. However the word-boundaries are useless, you can remove them. Show more code. Also, are you sure that newline sequences are only `\n` and not `\r\n` or `\r` or something more exotic? How many newlines do you want to keep?

Comment: Are you sure that `string` contains the whole text and not only a single line? (because obviously a single line can't contain two or more newline sequences as your pattern describes it). In this case, I repeat my previous advice: Show more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be

```
import re

string = """thisisaboutthen


Page 2 of 12

nowwearegoing

Page 3 of 12



"""

string = re.sub(r'\s*Page \d+ of \d+\s*', '', string)
print(string)
```

Which yields

```
thisisaboutthennowwearegoing
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/90ixqC/1).

Comment: Thank you Jan this worked perfectly. Also thanks for the helpful link - much easier than testing in python

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the context, but instead of specifying line breaks (`\n`) and spaces you can use `\s`. With `+` you say *regex* one or more.

```
import re
string = 'thisisaboutthen\n\n\nPage 2 of 12\n\nnowwearegoing\n\nPage 3 of 12\n\n\n'
pattern = r'\s+Page\s+\d+\s+of\s+\d+\s+'
print(re.sub(pattern, '', string))
```

With `\d` you choose numbers, With `\s` you choose space characters (space and \t, \n, \r, \f, \v). It may be useful to use [re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE).

Comment: for some reason this still didn't work, but Jans above did with the * instead of +. Thanks for explaining the use of \s though that will be helpful