# Find all integers in list of strings and output it in form of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I **find** and **extract integers** (without using the *re module*) from a **list** of **strings** and **integers**.

```
['My', '2', 'favorite', 'numbers', 'are', '42', 'and', '69']
```

How do I extract all the **integers** (2,42,69) in form of a list?
**Desired output:**

```
[2, 42, 69]
```

Comment: `[int(s) for s in my_list if s.isdigit()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution would be to try to cast the items to an `int` and keep those that succeed.

## List of any type:

```
result = []
for i in x:
    try:
        result.append(int(i))
    except Exception:
        pass

print(result)
>>[2, 42, 69]
```

## List Of Strings

As `Mateen Ulhaq` mentioned, if your input is always `string` type, it would be more appropriate to use:

```
[int(s) for s in my_list if s.isdigit()]
```

**Note:** This solution won't work if your string has negative numbers such as `'-12'`

Comment: Of course, one should avoid this solution since exceptions are costly.

Comment: Oh that's true! Just saw your comment, that's a good solution if we expect them all to be strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iterating over every element of list and try to convert it into an integer. If you get successful in the conversion then append it to the list of integers.

```
a = ['My', '2', 'favorite', 'numbers', 'are', '42', 'and', '69']
ints = []
for i in a:
    try:
        z = int(i)
        ints.append(z)
    except:
        pass
```

Or you could go with a oneliner from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
a = ['My', '2', 'favorite', 'numbers', 'are', '42', 'and', '69']
[int(s) for s in a if s.isdigit()]
#[2, 42, 69]
```