# How can I adjust my command

Tags: python, terminal

The command I am currently using to test my set is

```
python eval.py --test_data_path=PATH_TO_IMAGES --gpu_list=0 --checkpoint_path=/tmp/east_icdar2015_resnet_v1_50_rbox/ \
--output_dir=PATH_TO_END_LOCATION
```

However what I currently want to do, is to give them a file as input that file has the path of all the images instead of what I did before, supplying a folder with all the images inside.

The file's content will look a bit like this

```
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png
data/processed/10/blueprint-15.png
data/processed/10/blueprint-16.png
data/processed/10/blueprint-17.png
data/processed/10/blueprint-18.png
```

How can I adjust my command to do that task or even write a python code that will put all of them in a destination folder that I can reuse my first method on.

**Edit** : I figured out how to manage it but i need a regex that would take in the 2 numeric values, for example in the first line `data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png` i need a regex that will assign `10` to a variable `a` and `0` to a variable `b`.

Comment: To me, that you asked a question and, until other people answered, continued to (partially) solve your own question, thereby invalidating their answers, indicates that you shouldn't have asked (yet).

Comment: Actually the fact that i was still trying myself instead of sitting back waiting for answers should be taken as a positive sign not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do:

- Create an input file that contains the paths, e.g., infiles.txt
- Read the input file locations from this file
- use shutil.copy to copy your files to that location

Here's a sample code:

```
import os, shutil
from argparse import ArgumentParser as argpars
parser = argpars(description='')
parser.add_argument('--test_data_file', nargs=1, type=str)
parser.add_argument('--dest_loc', nargs=1, type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.test_data_file[0], 'r') as f:
    file_locations = [ff.strip() for ff in f.readlines()]


for loc in file_locations:
    print(os.path.join(args.dest_loc[0], loc.split('/')[-1]))
#   shutil.copy(loc, os.path.join(args.dest_loc[0], loc.split('/')[-1]))
```

The command is something like

```
python your_script.py --test_data_file infiles.txt --dest_loc some_folder
```

**Edit**
For the regex question:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\d+', 'data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png')
# or in the example above
re.findall(r'\d+', loc)
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answering that but meanwhile i typed my own code, however i need help with the regex part which is in the edit, kindly check and supply a helpful answer in that aspect if possible then i'll accept.

Comment: try:

    re.findall(r'\d+', 'data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png')

or

    re.findall(r'\d+', loc)

in the example above

Comment: Thank you i'll check 1 moment.

Comment: a more detailed answer to the regex question can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289348/5172579

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you need to change depends on how `test_data_path` is used in your program. If some part of your program later expects a list of files instead of a directory, it's trivial: `open` the file that is passed as an argument, call `list()` on it to get the names of the files, optionally validate that they exist, and pass the names on.

Comment: Kindly check my edit and supply help in the regex side if possible.