# Best way to add two numbers within a column that are seperated by brackets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that contains counts for different items as strings. Sometimes a restock is given in brackets. The list looks like this:

```
23
21 (+3)
32 (+14)
```

So there is always a space between the number and the brackets. To start of I've wrote a function that I apply over the Series. I've used the split-method two times to return only the first number:

```
splitted = item.split(" ")
splitted2 = splitted[0].split("+")
return int(splitted2[0])
```

This solution is kind of hacky already and on top of that, I am missing the restocks in brackets. Now I want to know, how I would possibly add both of the numbers together. I would therefore split the list one time so that I get this as a result:

```
['23']
['21', '(+3)']
```

Then I want to select only the list items, that have to values, get rid of the `+` and `()` and add the first and the second value together. How would I do that?

Comment: I get contradictory information - is it a list containing strings or a pandas dataframe? The example again looks rather like a text file.

Comment: What's the desired output for the same list you provided? Is it something like `[23, 24, 56]`, where all the values are integers?

Comment: The desired output are the sums as integers. 24 instead of 21 (+3). 

Sorry for the confusion: Right now I have the data in a pandas Series within a larger dataframe, but as strings. I'd convert it to whatever format needed to accomplish the desired effect.

Comment: @LennartThamm, did one of the below solutions solve your problem? If so, feel free to accept (tick on left), so other users know.

Comment: @ jp_data_analysis: Thanks for the insight. And thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of this question [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4289331/1924666)

```
str = "32 (+14)"
import re
data = re.findall(r'\d+', str)
# ['32', '14']
sum = 0
for d in data:
  sum+=int(d) 

print(sum)
```

Output:

```
46
```

See how numbers are parsed [using regex](https://regex101.com/r/KJeOPO/2). Here, `d` represents `[0-9]`

**Another** method: (with help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734634/1924666))

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "32 (+14)"
>>> eval(re.sub('[\(\)]', '', str.replace(' ', '')))
46
```

> This will also allow user to do any operation

Answer (score 3):

This is one way, which literally evaluates the '+' operation.

```
import ast, re

lst  = ['23', '21 (+3)', '32 (+14)']

lst = [ast.literal_eval(re.sub('[\(\)]', '', i.replace(' ', ''))) for i in lst]

# [23, 24, 46]
```

Comment: This one is better because here user can use any operator instead of add only. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

not the best method, but this works. regex will be better option.

```
>>> str = "32 (+14)"
>>> str.replace("(+", "").replace(")", "").split(" ")
['32', '14']
```

Regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "32 (+14)"
>>> nums = re.findall('\d+', str )
>>> print(sum(int(i) for i in nums))
46
```

Comment: What if there is no space `32(+14)`? in your 1st approach