# Get imaginary and real part of value from the complex number "92+23i"?

Tags: python, string, numbers, extract

I want to extract numbers from a string and store them in different variables.

for eg:- `"92+23i"` is a complex number. I want to store 92 in variable `num_real` and 23 in `num_imagin`.

Answer (score 2):

Python has predefined type as [**`complex`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex) however it expects the string to be of type `"a+bj"` *(note the `j` instead of `i`, and it should be without space)*. In your case you may replace `"i"` with `"j"` in your string and get your desired values as:

```
>>> my_str = "92+23i"
>>> my_num = complex(my_str.replace('i', 'j'))
```

From this complex number, you need to extract the desired values using `my_num.imag` for imaginary part and `my_num.real` for the real part of the complex number. For example:

```
>>> my_num.imag
23.0
>>> my_num.real
92.0
```

Comment: That was just an example , i mean '23x + 23y = 0' and extract the numbers only .

Comment: @WILDFIRE Your question was unclear then. For this, you might need to take a look at: [*Python: Extract numbers from a string*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: those answer are beyond my understandings.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is very close to parsing as a Python literal:

```
>>> s = '92+23i'
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s.replace('i', 'j'))
(92+23j)
```

Access the real and imaginary parts with `num.real` and `num.imag`.

Comment: I don't understand .