# how to extract part of string in python (the string length may vary)

Tags: python, string

I'm having this string in my app which stores different percentage, I want to just extract the percentage value and convert it to int( ). My String looks something like this..

note: there will be one or more blank space(s) before the number.

```
result ='bFilesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on\n/dev/sda4 30G 20G 8.4G 71% /\n'
percentage = getPercentage(result)   #This method should output 71 in this example
print("Percentage is: ", percentage)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well is it always like that? Then you could use a simple split function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a positive lookahead **`regex`**:

```
import re

result = 'demo percentage is   18%'
percentage = re.search(r'\d+(?=%)', result)        
print("Percentage is: ", percentage.group())

# Percentage is:  18
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression:

```
import re

inp_str = "demo percentage is   18%"
x = re.findall(r'\d+(?=%)', inp_str)
# x is a list of all numbers appeared in the input string
x = [int(i) for i in x]
print(x) # prints - [18]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `inp_str = "demo 11 percentage is   18%"`.

Comment: Yes, I know that my solution will not handle the above scenario but the question was not asked only to extract numbers that precede the `%` sign. Anyway,  I have updated the answer.

Comment: result ='bFilesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on\n/dev/sda4        30G   20G  8.4G  71% /\n' this is my string to be precise

Comment: @ManojJahgirdar please mention your requirements precisely from next time :)

Comment: @WasiAhmad yes sorry for the inconvenience. thank you.. :)