# Extract numbers from strings from a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, isnull

I have a dataframe called data, I am trying to clean one of the columns in the dataframe so I can convert the price into numerical values only.
This is how I'm filtering for the column to find those incorrect values.
`data[data['incorrect_price'].astype(str).str.contains('[A-Za-z]')]`

```
    Incorrect_Price    Occurences   errors
23  99 cents                732       1
50  3 dollars and 49 cents  211       1
72  the price is 625        128       3
86  new price is 4.39       19        2
138 4 bucks                 3         1
199 new price 429           13        1
225 price is 9.99           5         1
240 new price is 499        8         2
```

I have tried `data['incorrect_Price'][20:51].str.findall(r"(\d+) dollars")` and `data['incorrect_Price'][20:51].str.findall(r"(\d+) cents")` to find rows that have "cents" and "dollars" in them so I can extract the dollar and cents amount but haven't been able to incorporate this when iterating over all rows in the dataframe.

```
  I would like the results to like look this:  

    Incorrect_Price        Desired    Occurences    errors
23  99 cents                .99           732         1
50  3 dollars and 49 cents  3.49          211         1
72  the price is 625        625           128         3
86  new price is 4.39       4.39           19         2
138 4 bucks                 4.00           3          1
199 new price 429           429            13         1
225 price is 9.99           9.99           5          1
240 new price is 499        499            8          2
```

Comment: For starters, there is no column 'Shopper_Entered_Price' in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can be relatively easily solved as long as the strings `Incorrect_Price` retain the structure you present in the examples (numbers are not expressed in words).

Using regular expressions you can extract number part and optional "cent"/"cents" or "dollar"/"dollars" using an approach from [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string). The two main differences is that you are looking for pairs of numerical value and "cent[s]" or "dollar[s]" and that they potentially occur more than once.

```
import re


def extract_number_currency(value):
    prices  = re.findall('(?P<value>[\d]*[.]?[\d]{1,2})\s*(?P<currency>cent|dollar)s?', value)

    result = 0.0
    for value, currency in prices:
        partial = float(value)
        if currency == 'cent':
            result += partial / 100
        else:
            result += partial

    return result


print(extract_number_currency('3 dollars and 49 cent'))
```

> ```
> 3.49
> ```

Now, what you need is to apply this function to all incorrect values in the column with prices in words. For simplicity I am applying it here to all values (but I am sure you will be able to deal with the subset):

```
data['Desired'] = data['Incorrect_Price'].apply(extract_number_currency)
```

Voila!

---

Breaking down of the regex `'(?P<value>[\d]*[.]?[\d]{1,2})\s*(?P<currency>cent|dollar)s?'`

There are two capture *named* groups `(?P<name_of_the_capture_group> .... )`

The first capture group `(?P<value>[\d]*[.]?[\d]{1,2})` captures:

`[\d]` - digits

`[\d]*` - repeated 0 or more times

`[.]?` - followed by optional (`?`) dot

`[\d]{1,2}` - followed by a digit repeated from 1 to 2 times

`\s*` - denotes 0 or more whitespaces

Now the 2nd capture group which is much simpler: `(?P<currency>cent|dollar)`

`cent|dollar` - it boils down to alternative between `cent` and `dollar` strings being captured

`s?` is an optional plural of 'cent *s*' or 'dollar *s*'

Comment: wow that is super impressive. thank you so much! is there anyway you could provide a breakdown of the regex logic please?