# Python generator in print statement

Tags: python-3.x

I try to separate digits from a string with some simple code:

```
d=['72olle' ,'103doo', '100ya']

def only_digit (data):
    return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(),(i for i in data)))

for i in d:
    print(only_digit(i))

print(only_digit(i for i in d))
```

and can't get why does first print works but second doesn't

Comment: It works to me!

Comment: Hey @Spl! What exactly did you expect to happen when running the second print statement? - What is your output supposed to look like?

Comment: I thought that two statements are equal, but second didn't work. I want to clarify to myself why it won't work. And i steel don't understand ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you some info on what is being passed to the only_digit function and what's being returned.

```
d=['72olle' ,'103doo', '100ya']

def only_digit (data):
    print(type(data)," => ",data)
    theReturn = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(),(i for i in data)))
    print(type(theReturn)," => ",theReturn)
    return theReturn

for i in d:
    print(only_digit(i))

print(only_digit(i for i in d))
```

Output:

```
>>> for i in d:
...     print(only_digit(i))
...
<type 'str'>  => ' 72olle '
<type 'str'>  => ' 72 '
72
<type 'str'>  => ' 103doo '
<type 'str'>  => ' 103 '
103
<type 'str'>  => ' 100ya '
<type 'str'>  => ' 100 '
100
>>> print(only_digit(i for i in d))
<type 'generator'>  => ' <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000001F764C8> '
<type 'str'>  => '  '
```

Comment: I see... all that functional orientated staff looks great but cause so many troubles (
Maybe you can show how it should look in a proper functional-style way, thanks for the help )

Comment: @Spl Not sure what you mean by functional-style.

Comment: @Spl Not sure what you mean by functional-style.
Since it looks like you want to do the same as in the first case but in a single line that would be:

`print '\n'.join([only_digit(i) for i in d])`

`[only_digit(i) for i in d]` is a list comprehension, a for loop in a single line.

That returns a list, in this case the results of `only_digit(i)`.

Then we join the elements of the list with a new-line, which gives us a string and print it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same operation with this different approach, also I think is more easy to understand. Using [**findall()**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall) function from [**re**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) module:

```
import re

d=['72olle' ,'103doo', '100ya']
print([re.findall(r'\d+', i)[0] for i in d])
```

Output:

> `['72', '103', '100']`

*References: [Python: Extract number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)*

Comment: If you know RegEx you can understand this, but claiming that using Regex makes anything easier to understand is bold ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are right some RegEx statements are complicated but in this case... it's enoughly easy to use it ;)