# How to use regexp to extract the digit within { customer:490 } bought a car { car:6441 }

Tags: regex

I have a json object with value in this pattern:
{ customer:1501 } bought a car { car:6333 }
How to use regexp to extract the digit of customer and car.
I am very new to regex, I can only extract the string between the curly braces. I am not sure should I do it separately, i.e. extract the string between the curly braces than extract the digits after "customer:" or "car:". Please help

Comment: If you want to use regexp yo extract the numbers from the string, try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match the curly braces and match `customer` or `car` and then the digits, and capture your digits from group1,

```
{\s*(?:customer|car):(\d+)\s*}
```

**Explanation of regex:**

- `{` - Match a literal `{`
- `\s*` - Match optional whitespace
- `(?:customer|car):` - Match either `customer` or `car` literally followed by a colon
- `(\d+)` - Matched one or more digits and capture it in group1
- `\s*}` - Match optional space then closing curly bracket `}`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tKg3gk/1)**

Let me know if you have any issues further.