# How to split a string into a list by skipping letters and ^ char

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
string_a = 81^A55
```

from which I'm trying to get the following list

```
string_a_int = [81,55]
```

I'm able to split the string into a list made by numbers as follows

```
list_only_number = re.split('[A-Z]+', string_a)

list_only_numbers = [81^, 55]
```

but I'm trying to figure out how to skip also the `^`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289348/3832970

Comment: Note that `^A` is the [caret-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) of the `\x01` / SOH / Start Of Header control character. It seems likely to me that you should be handling a string that contains that actual character rather than its caret notation, at which point you could simply split over that character.