# I want no add all the numbers in my string

Tags: python-3.x

I want no add all the numbers in my string

```
info="10-20,30,40-50,60,70-80"

    print(sum([int(a) for a in info.split(",")[::2].split("-")])+sum([int(b) for b in info.split(",")[1::2]]))
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289348/11573842

Comment: Why did you not do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Python person, so there is definitely a better way to do this, but here is a step-by-step way to get to your desired result.  Hopefully, the comments are explanatory.  I also commented out several `print()` statements that you can re-add if you want to see what transformations happen at each step:

```
x="10-20,30,40-50,60,70-80"

# Do a first split
xList = x.split(',')
#print(xList)

# Get the non-ranges into their own list
listOfSingles = []
xListSingleNumsOnly = list(filter(lambda x: '-' not in x, xList))
for a in xListSingleNumsOnly:
    listOfSingles.append(int(a))

# Get the sum of the non-ranges
listOfSinglesSum = sum(listOfSingles)
#print(listOfSinglesSum)

# Get the ranges into their own list
xListRangesOnly = list(filter(lambda x: '-' in x, xList))
#print(xListRangesOnly)

# Turn the ranges that are currently strings into ints and populate them
# Start with an empty list to hold results of transformations
listOfRanges = []

# Split on the dash
for i in xListRangesOnly:
    iSplit = i.split('-')
    # For each (pseudo-)range, populate it
    listedInts = []
    for x in iSplit:
        listedInts.append(int(x))
    ranged = list(range(listedInts[0],listedInts[1]+1))
    # Add up these ranges
    rangeSum = sum(ranged)
    listOfRanges.append(rangeSum)

# Sum the ranges you just populated
listOfRangesSum = sum(listOfRanges)
#print(listOfRangesSum)

final = listOfSinglesSum + listOfRangesSum
print(final)
```

Answer (score -1):

Import regular expression library and using findall method, set a search pattern in order to get integers from string.

```
import re
    sum([int(i) for i in re.findall(pattern="\d[,]?[-]?\d",string=info)])
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.