# How to replace all square brackets and their values with empty strings?

Tags: python

How to replace all square brackets and their values with empty strings if you don't know how many square brackets are there?

```
data = "[a] 1 [b] test [c] other characters"
```

I want the data to be `" 1  test other characters"`.

Comment: ``import re;  re.findall("\d+", data)`` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I guess, the question is not about numbers, but about brackets, because there can be anything inside. Can there be nested brackets though?

Comment: @Sushanth This would work if there are no digits inside the brackets, and the parts outside are only made of digits.

Comment: What you have shown as desired output does not match the description in the text. Why should the output be `[ 1 2 ]` and not `1 2`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right, I have modified the question.

Comment: @bereal Yes, thanks for your reminding, i have modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string on the bracket parts using a regex:

```
import re

data = "[a] 1 [b] 2 [c]"

parts = re.split(r'\[.*?\]', data)
# ['', ' 1 ', ' 2 ', '']
out = '[' + ' '.join(parts) + ']'
print(out)
# [  1   2  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Another verbose answer would be:

```py
import re
data = "[a] 1 [b] test [c] other characters"

pattern = '\[.*?\]' #any character(s) with [ ]

unwanted = set(re.findall(pattern,data))

results = ' '.join(i for i in data.split() 
                   if i not in unwanted)

print(results)
# 1 test other characters
```

**Updated**
Addition condition
Problem  > "[a] 1 [b] test [1] other [c]haracters"
Due to `.split()` this will not be replaced

```
import re

data = "[a] 1 [b] test [1] other [c]haracters"

pattern = '\[.*?\]' #any character(s) with [ ]

print(re.sub(pattern,'',data))
# " 1  test  other  haracters"
```

To remove the extra spaces

```py
_ = re.sub(pattern,'',data).split()
print(' '.join(i for i in _ if i))

# "1 test other haracters"
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the data is  "[a] 1 [b] test [c]other characters", the result will contain [c], because you use data.split(), if ']' not followed by space, the output will not be expected.

Comment: I did not know about that scenario! Let me update the code

Answer (score -1):

Try regex substitute.

```
import re

data = "[a] 1 [b] 2 [c]"
new = re.sub("([[a-z]*])", "", data)
```

Comment: Output: `'1 2 [c]'`

Comment: A yes, fair point, the type here is the space between ] and ) in the refer. I'll edit.