# How to filter out numbers from a string if it matches the template?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python. I have a long string that has several numbers in it. I only need the numbers that matches the
XX XX XXXXXX form (ex. 15 09 066456). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: regex is your friend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not allowed to comment, so posting the possible solution(using regex) here, python 3.x

```
import re
text='15 09 066456'
pattern = r'\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{6}'
match= re.findall(pattern,text)
print(match)
```

Comment: Why would you want to comment this?

Comment: for providing help

Comment: its working good but it only outputs only one XX XX XXXXXX code. How can I get more? Edit: Figured it out: `pattern = r'\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{6}'
match = re.findall(pattern,text)
print(match)`

Comment: @Hackry As already suggested by you, re.findall will do the needful to find all the matching patterns. Same Edit is done in the answer above. Thanks