# split a string of numbers into a list

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a string of List of Numbers as follow:
(the whole List is stored as a string)

```
"[{'3', '4', '10', '11'}, {'13', '16', '17', '19'}]"
```

and i want to select only the numbers and assign them to a list, like this

```
['3', '4', '10', '11', '13', '16', '17', '19']
```

i tried to use split() but i have the Following result:

```
['3', '4', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '3', '1', '6', '1', '7', '1', '9']
```

how can i do This please.

Comment: You are asking two things at once. The linked question contains the answer to the first problem.

Comment: Alternatively, the solution to the problem if you do not care about the data structure is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regex` to rescue

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

```
# coding=utf8

import re

regex = r"[0-9]+"

test_str = "\"[{'3', '4', '10', '11'}, {'13', '16', '17', '19'}]\""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

```
['3', '4', '10', '11', '13', '16', '17', '19']
```

Comment: yeah this works thanks. but what if i want to have each part separatly like this : ['3', '4', '10', '11'] ['13', '16', '17', '19'] !