# Extract integer from string with Python

Tags: python, split

May I know other approach to extract the `int` from a string.

```
str_int='S1'

int ( "".join ( [xx for xx in list ( str_int) if xx.isdigit ()] ) )
```

I think my current approach is overkill.
Should this post is considered duplicate,please link me to the appropriate OP.

Comment: use regex `\d+`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: The optimal solution depends on the structure of the string. For example, if there are always 4 letters before the integer, int(s[4:]) is better than a regex :)

Comment: @costaparas Nope, the problem is based on word and number separated by space

Comment: @balandongiv Please give us a couple of example strings.

Comment: Hi @kol, the problem consist of more than single digit (e.g., S1 S11 S111 etc). But based on your suggestion, I think I can omit the first letter and convert the rest of the str as int. Thanks for the idea btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the problem consist of more than single digit (e.g., S1 S11 S111 etc)"

Simply remove the first character and convert the rest to integer: `int(s[1:])`

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex:

```
import re
str_int='S1'
my_digits = re.findall(r'\d+', str_int)
print(my_digits)


## output
['1']
```