# Python parse only digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I want to parse only digit , for example I parse numbers of users sessions last 5 min , userSes = "12342 last 5 min" , I want to parse only 12342 (this number change every 5 min) , but when I parse this data result is 12342 and 5 ( this number is "from last 5 min " 's number) can any one help me ?

```
x= ('12342 from last 5 min ')
print(''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(),x)))
```

Comment: `x.split()[0]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re

x = '12342 from last 5 min '
n_sessions = int(re.findall('^(\d+).*', x)[0])
print(n_sessions)
```

`^(\d+) .*` looks for a number (`\d+`) at the start of the string (`^`) before the space and everything else (`.*`).

If your string is consistent

```
n_sessions = int(x.split()[0])
```

should be enough.

Comment: Error:  n_sessions = int(re.findall('^(\d+) .*', data.text)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This is my script
driver.get(example.com)
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chartTotalBetsDiv"]/div[3]')
n_sessions = int(re.findall('^(\d+) .*', data.text)[0])
print(n_sessions)

Comment: Print `data.text` and see if it has a string as you've described in your post

Comment: it's <class 'str'>

Comment: `print(data.text)` gives you `<class 'str'>`?

Comment: Yes Result like this "1233214 from 5 last min"

Comment: `re.findall('^(\d+) .*', "1233214 from 5 last min")[0]` gives me the correct result. Please include this part of your code in your question so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
parsed_list = [item for item in x.split(' ')[0] if item.isdigit()]
print(''.join(parsed_list))
```

Comment: This will produce the same result as OP's code

Comment: I got it. You are right. I corrected my code))