# reformat row count in sqalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, count, sqlalchemy, string-formatting

I'm running a simple command to fetch and print the number of rows in a table within a MySQL db so that RunDeck can log it, and was hoping for either some help with formatting the result or a prettier way to do it.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

devhost = 'host'
devuser = 'user'
devpassword = 'scipiodestroyedhannibalatzama'

engine = f"mysql+pymysql://{devuser}:{devpassword}@{devhost}/germans_got_lucky"
connection = create_engine(engine)

rows = str(connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(Day) FROM teutoburg_forest").fetchall())
    print(rows)
```

returns

```
[(1706,)]
```

but I'd like it to return

```
1706
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities here, first:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

devhost = 'host'
devuser = 'user'
devpassword = 'scipiodestroyedhannibalatzama'

engine = f"mysql+pymysql://{devuser}:{devpassword}@{devhost}/germans_got_lucky"
connection = create_engine(engine)

rows = len(connection.execute("SELECT Day FROM teutoburg_forest").fetchall())
print(rows)
```

The second:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

devhost = 'host'
devuser = 'user'
devpassword = 'scipiodestroyedhannibalatzama'

engine = f"mysql+pymysql://{devuser}:{devpassword}@{devhost}/germans_got_lucky"
connection = create_engine(engine)

rows = connection.execute("SELECT Day FROM teutoburg_forest").count
print(rows)
```

or the third:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

devhost = 'host'
devuser = 'user'
devpassword = 'scipiodestroyedhannibalatzama'

engine = f"mysql+pymysql://{devuser}:{devpassword}@{devhost}/germans_got_lucky"
connection = create_engine(engine)

rows = connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(Day) FROM teutoburg_forest").fetchone()
print(rows[0])
```

Comment: option 3 is much cleaner than what i was using.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`.scalar()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.scalar) gives what you need:

```
conn.execute(text("SELECT count(tickers.ticker) FROM tickers")).scalar()
```

*I also used [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) clause as it is required in `sqlalchemy>=1.4`*

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51312242/8922198) worked perfectly to strip away the unneeded characters.

```
rows = str(connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(Day) FROM teutoburg_forest").fetchall())
print(rows)
[(1706,)]
print(''.join([n for n in rows if n.isdigit()]))
1706
```