# How to extract a number from an alphanumeric string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I want to extract numbers contained in an alphanumeric strings. Please help me on this.

Example:

```
line = ["frame_117", "frame_11","frame_1207"]
```

Result:

```
[117, 11, 1207]
```

Comment: Try: `[int(s.split('_')[-1]) for s in line]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split with special character '_' like this:

```
numbers = []
line = ["frame_117", "frame_11","frame_1207"]
for item in line:
    number = int(item.split("_",1)[1])
    numbers.append(number)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
temp = []
lines = ["frame_117", "frame_11","frame_1207"]
for line in lines:
    num = re.search(r'-?\d+', line)
    temp.append(int(num.group(0)))

print(temp) # [117, 11, 1207]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rationale

The first thing I see is that the names inside the list have a pattern. The string `frame`, an underscore `_` and the string `number`:  `"frame_number"`.

## Step-By-Step

With that in mind, you can:

1. Loop through the list. We'll use a list comprehension.
2. Get each item from the list (the names=`"frame_number"` )
3. Split them according to a separator (getting a sublist with [`"frame"`, `"number"`])
4. And then create a new list with the last items of each sublist

```
numbers = [x.split("_")[-1] for x in line]
['117', '11', '1207']
```

## Solution

5. But you need numbers and here you have a list of strings. We make one extra step and use `int()`.

```
numbers = [int(x.split("_")[-1]) for x in line]
[117, 11, 1207]
```

---

This works only because we detected a pattern in the target name.

But what happens if you need to find all numbers in a random string? Or floats? Or Complex numbers? Or negative numbers?

That's a little bit more complex and out of scope of this answer.
See [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python/4289415#4289415)