# about Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I made this code:

```
import re

match = re.search(r'[DER]\d+[Y]', 'DER1234Y' )  
print(match.group())
```

and it prints this :

```
R1234Y
```

I want the code to only print the numbers and nothing else. How to do that ?

Comment: Put `\d+` into parentheses and retrieve first capturing group using `match.group(1)`.

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: If that is what you want, then why do you have `[MOD]` and `[X]` in your regex?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake I fixed it

Comment: in addition to Olvin's solution, you can also use lookaheads / lookbehinds: `(?<=DER)\d+(?=Y)`. For your information, `[DER]` means "match one character that could be D, E or R".

Answer (score -1):

It's basically regex. So would this work?: `re.sub('[^0-9]+', '', 'DER1234Y')`

`[^0-9]+` = everything that is **not** a numeric value (**0-9**).