# How to loop through a string of letters and numbers and identify which are numbers?

Tags: python, string, loops

I am writing some code, and would like to add a conditional statement such that as we loop through `stringg` below, if we hit an integer, then ... we do something (doesn't matter what)

```
stringg = "3[a]2[bc]"
```

But the thing is that even the 3 and 2 are strings at the moment- how can I loop through stringg while checking if each character is an integer?

```
for i in stringg: 
    if isinstance(i,int): 
        print("Hello")
```

The above loop `returns nothing` to my point made above. Any ideas how the above can be achieved?

One other thing that came to mind is to do int(i) as we loop, but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Comment: strings in python has "isdigit" and "isnumeric" as functions you could use.

Comment: The accepted answer on the proposed duplicate will not work here. The OP cannot split by whitespace. The [2nd highest voted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289348/6162307) does cover this case as well though.

Answer (score 0):

```
stringg = "3[a]2[bc]"

for ch in stringg:
    if ch.isnumeric():
        print(ch)
```

Comment: Consider explaining your code