# Sort a pandas dataframe by 2 columns (one with integers, one with alphanumerics) with priority for integer column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe with two columns.

One column has integers: 1,2,3, .... 10,11,12, ...

One column has alphanumerics (as strings): A1, A2, ... A10, A11, ... B1, B2, ... B10, B11 ... (always one letter + one or two numbers, letters A-H, numbers 1-12)

Goal is to sort the dataframe by the integer column ascending with first priority, and by the alphanumerical column with second priority. **The alphanumerical column should be sorted like this**: A1, B1, C1, D1, ... A2, B2, C2, D2, ..., A3, B3, C3, D3, ...

(this is a problem from biology/wetlab/robotics/automation/96-well plates).

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-by-multiple-columns-in-python

Comment: @hickz what you want is called natural sorting, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69036366/16343464)

Comment: This is NOT natural sorting.  Natural sorting will sort with A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3,  but OP want the number be the major sort key and sorted first.  A1, B1, C1, A2, C2, B2, A3, B3, C3.

Comment: You're right, my bad, I misread.

Comment: No problem, it's easily misread.  I also misread initially. :-)

Comment: @SeaBean fixed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. Split the second column with alphanumeric strings into 2 columns: one column `Letter` to hold the first letter and another column `Number` to hold a number of one or two digits.
2. Convert `Number` column from string to integer.
3. Then, sort these 2 new columns together with the first column of integers

Let's illustrate the process with an example below:

Assume we have the dataframe `df` as follows:

```
print(df)

   Col1 Col2
0     2  B12
1    11   C2
2     2   A1
3    11   B2
4     2   B1
5    11  C12
6     2  A12
7    11   C1
8     2   A2
```

**Step 1 & 2: Split `Col2` into 2 columns `Letter` & `Number` + Convert `Number` column from string to integer:**

```
df['Letter'] = df['Col2'].str[0]               # take 1st char
df['Number'] = df['Col2'].str[1:].astype(int)  # take 2nd char onwards and convert to integer
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Col1 Col2 Letter  Number
0     2  B12      B      12
1    11   C2      C       2
2     2   A1      A       1
3    11   B2      B       2
4     2   B1      B       1
5    11  C12      C      12
6     2  A12      A      12
7    11   C1      C       1
8     2   A2      A       2
```

**Step 3: Sort `Col1`, `Letter` and `Number` with priority: `Col1` ---> `Number` ---> `Letter`:**

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Col1', 'Number', 'Letter'])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Col1 Col2 Letter  Number
2     2   A1      A       1
4     2   B1      B       1
8     2   A2      A       2
6     2  A12      A      12
0     2  B12      B      12
7    11   C1      C       1
3    11   B2      B       2
1    11   C2      C       2
5    11  C12      C      12
```

After sorting, you can remove the `Letter` and `Number` columns, as follows:

```
df = df.drop(['Letter', 'Number'], axis=1)
```

**If you want to do all in one step**, you can also chain the instructions, as follows:

```
df = (df.assign(Letter=df['Col2'].str[0], 
                Number=df['Col2'].str[1:].astype(int))
        .sort_values(by=['Col1', 'Number', 'Letter'])
        .drop(['Letter', 'Number'], axis=1)
     )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Col1 Col2
2     2   A1
4     2   B1
8     2   A2
6     2  A12
0     2  B12
7    11   C1
3    11   B2
1    11   C2
5    11  C12
```

Comment: @hickz  Pleased to help!  Happy programming & have a nice weekend :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you could separate your alphanumerical column first and then sort it accordingly. You could:

```
df['numericalValue'] = df['alphaNumerical'][1:] # Assuming you only have 1 letter

df = df.sort_values(['numericalValue', 'alphaNumerical'], ascending = (True, True))
```

This would first sort your dataframe by the numerical value, as shown in your example and then secondarily sort the values that share the same numerical value by its letter.

If you have a variable number of non-numeric characters you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python):

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` argument of sort_values. Just apply a transformation to change 'B1' to '01B':

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['C1', 'C1', 'A2', 'B12', 'B1','B2'],
                   'col2': [2,1,3,4,2,5]})

(df.sort_values(by='col2')
   .sort_values(by='col1',
                key=lambda x: x.str[1:].str.pad(2, 'left', '0')+x.str[0])
)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
4   B1     2
1   C1     1
0   C1     2
2   A2     3
5   B2     5
3  B12     4
```