# Pandas: Create new column and add value depending on value (substring) in a string column and value on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question, I did hunt around a bit before I felt like I had to post a question.

I am trying to assign a value in a new column `devicevalue` based on a value of another 2 columns. My dataframe looks a bit like this;

```
devicename           make     devicevalue
switch1               cisco        0
switch1-web100        netgear      0  
switch10              cisco        0
switch23              cisco        1
switch31-web200       netgear      0
switch31              cisco        1
switch41-new          cisco        1
switch40e             cisco        1
switch31-web200-new   netgear      0
switch40e             cisco        1
switch11-data100e     netgear      0
```

I am trying to add a value depending on these criteria;

- If `make == netgear` (set to 0)
- If the value after switch is 20 or greater (set to 1, otherwise set to 0)

**(If both conditions met, set to 0, i.e. condition of *"`make == netgear` set to 0"* takes precedence.** Note that this is different from the existing codes where the 2nd condition override (and overwrite result value) if both conditions met.)

I originally had some help getting this together however some devices now have a `-new` and `p`or `a` or `e` which breaks the code that looking at a number at the end of the string

The code I am using is essentially;

```
def get_number_suffix(devicename: str) -> int:
    i = 1
    while i < len(devicename) and devicename[-i:].isnumeric():
        i += 1

    return int(devicename[-(i-1):])


def compute_devicevalue(row) -> int:
    if 'netgear' in row['make']:
        return 0
    if 20 <= get_number_suffix(row['devicename']):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['devicevalue'] = df.apply(compute_devicevalue, axis=1)
```

this worked fine before the new additions to the end of some of the naming, now it obviously breaks.
I have tried all sorts of ways but I can't find a decent way that ignores `-new` and `p`or `a` or `e`

**edit**

Sorry all, I completely messed up what I was trying to ask, I'm trying to do the value based on the value after `'switch'`.

Essentially using the existing code when it converts the string to an integer and does `len` it falls over on any name that has a `-new` and `p`or `a` or `e` following it

as an example saying

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'switch23-new'

Comment: Why the value in switch31 is 1?

Comment: Why does switch10 cisco have a value of 0 but switch23 cisco has a value of 1?

Comment: Your output is inconsistent with your conditions.

Comment: Whenever 2 conditions of setting to 1 and 0 co-exist, what should we set ?  E.g.  make == netgear and web or data >= 200 at the same time ?

Comment: ah damn, sorry I messed up the example, very sorry sleep deprived new dad.

I'll tidy up the original example above

Comment: @Uggers  I've edited my solution above to extract the numbers after 'switch' instead. Please take a look.  One thing still outstanding to clarify with you is when both the conditions of make == netgear and the number after switch >= 20, what will be the required value? 0 or 1 ?  Seen your edited example you seems want 0, but from your original codes sequence (i.e. your current processing) seems will give 1 since the logic of setting 0 for make == netgear is before checking value of number after switch and will be overwritten to 1 in this case.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Uggers  my current solution above keeps your original code sequence and in the case of both conditions met will set to 1.  But if you want 0 instead, you can simply move my codes of setting 0 for make == netgear to the end after setting 1 for switch case.

Comment: thanks SeaBean will give it a whirl see if it fixes my issues,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), as follows:

```
df['devicevalue'] = 0     # init value to 0

# Set to 1 if the value after 'switch' >= 20. 
# Otherwise part is set during init to 0 at the first statement
df.loc[df['devicename'].str.extract(r'switch(\d+)', expand=False).astype(float) >= 20, 'devicevalue'] = 1

# Set to 0 if `make` == 'netgear'
df.loc[df['make'] == 'netgear', 'devicevalue'] = 0 
# If you have 2 or more values of `make` to match, use, e.g.:
#df.loc[df['make'].isin(['netgear', 'dell']), 'devicevalue'] = 0
```

Regex `r'switch(\d+)'` works together with [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the digits after `'switch'` no matter they are at the end or in the middle.  Therefore, it solves your problem of having the digits previously at the end now at the middle.

Result:

```
             devicename     make  devicevalue
0               switch1    cisco            0
1        switch1-web100  netgear            0
2              switch10    cisco            0
3              switch23    cisco            1
4       switch31-web200  netgear            0
5              switch31    cisco            1
6          switch41-new    cisco            1
7             switch40e    cisco            1
8   switch31-web200-new  netgear            0
9             switch40e    cisco            1
10    switch11-data100e  netgear            0
```

Comment: Doesn't match OP's output. "netgear" in row 8 has a value of 1. I'm unsure what OP needs though.

Comment: @not_speshal  Yes, I guess OP's set the desired output quite random.  Not adhere to his own data.

Comment: Correct - the output doesn't match the stated requirements.

Comment: Prefer `.str.extract('(?:web|data)(\d+)', expand=False)` instead of `.str.extract(r'(?:web|data)(\d+)')[0]`. IMHO

Comment: @Corralien  Right, that's better.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Shouldn't this statement `df.loc[df['make'] == 'netgear', 'devicevalue'] = 0 ` be after loc statement bcz in ur output `netgar` rows have device value of 1 while it should be zero

Comment: @MuhammadHassan  Good point!  Thanks!  Then it no longer redundant even when we init to 0 at the beginning.  Thanks for pointing up to swap the sequence :-)   Anyway, I think better clarify with OP.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan  Before clarified with OP, better place the netgear condition before the web/data condition.  This is because OP's old program logics is also in this order.

Comment: Very sorry, I meant the value after switch, not the 3 digit value, really REALLY appreciate the help looking at this though.

Comment: I this appears to have worked perfectly, one quick question. 
How would I go about adding say new models to ignore.

For example netgear and dell

Either of these don't seem to work;

'df.loc[df['make'] == 'netgear', 'devicevalue'] = 0 '
'df.loc[df['make'] == 'dell', 'devicevalue'] = 0 '

'df.loc[df['make'] == 'netgear' or df['make'] == 'dell' or , 'devicevalue'] = 0'

Comment: sorry messed up formating; `df.loc[df['make'] == 'netgear', 'devicevalue'] = 0 `
`df.loc[df['make'] == 'dell', 'devicevalue'] = 0 `
or
`df.loc[df['make'] == 'netgear' or df['make'] == 'dell' or , 'devicevalue'] = 0 `

Comment: @Uggers you can use `df.loc[df['make'].isin(['netgear', 'dell']), 'devicevalue'] = 0`  Simply use `.isin` and put the items in a list.

Comment: that worked perfectly, I did have to adjust the order the df.loc's were.  I added the device name first to set all 20 or higher to =1 then set specific makes back to 0 again as if I did make first it would get set back to 1 again when the device name portion check.

Comment: @Uggers  That's great you got it.  Remember to accept my solution and also upvote if you have not already done so.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with regex to extract number from string, here for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python).

For my simplicity I converted your dataframe to list

`a = [{"devicename" : "switch1","make": "cisco", "devicevalue" :0}, {"devicename" : "switch1-web100", "make" : "netgear", "devicevalue" :0}, {"devicename" : "switch10" ,  "make" : "cisco", "devicevalue" :0}.... ]`

Then I used this function to do it:

```
import re

def clean_data(data):
    for i in range(len(data)): #remove this if using dataframe row
        row = data[i] #Dict
        if row["make"] == "netgear":
            row["devicevalue"] = 0
        
        tmp = -1
        if "web" in row["devicename"]:
            tmp = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+', row["devicename"].split("web")[1])][0]
        elif "data" in row["devicename"]:
            tmp = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+', row["devicename"].split("data")[1])][0]

        if tmp >= 200:
            row["devicevalue"] = 0
        elif tmp == -1:
            pass #Nothing to change

        data[i] = row 
    return data #remove this and return row
```

I get the following

```
[{'devicename': 'switch1', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 0}, {'devicename': 'switch1-web100', 'make': 'netgear', 'devicevalue': 0}, {'devicename': 'switch10', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 0}, {'devicename': 'switch23', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 1}, {'devicename': 'switch31-web200', 'make': 'netgear', 'devicevalue': 0}, {'devicename': 'switch31', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 1}, {'devicename': 'switch40', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 1}, {'devicename': 'switch23', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 1}, {'devicename': 'switch31-web200-new', 'make': 'netgear', 'devicevalue': 0}, {'devicename': 'switch31-web100a', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 1}, {'devicename': 'switch40', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 1}, {'devicename': 'switch11-data100e', 'make': 'cisco', 'devicevalue': 1}]
```

Since you are sending rows of dataframe, remove the outer loop and return row instead of data in your code