# How to extract specific content in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, extract, python-re

I want to extract specific content from string.
Consider the following dataframe:

```
data = {'time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'id': ["bike0", "bike10", "veh0", "veh10", "moto100"]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to extract with a regular expression the digit value in the string.
The final result should be:

```
data = {'time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'id': [0, 10, 0, 10, 100]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The difficulty here is that the length of the string and the number of digits to extract are variable.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab a sequence of digits at the end of each string in the `id` column, then covert them integers and reassign to the `id` column.

```
df['id'] = df.id.str.extract(r'(\d+)$').astype(int)
```

Comment: are you sure? it raises an  `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  The error indicates you are trying access the `id` attribute of a dictionary, not a data frame.  Did you run it on `data` by mistake?

Comment: @XxJames07-, the answer from @James also works (python3.6) so I've upvoted it. For sure you have used `data.id` instead of `df.id`. Maybe you can post also the line above `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'` from stack trace.

Comment: yes, sorry for my mistake, i forgot to say i've tested it and it works, thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I hope that below code is OK. It removes all alpha characters. You can extend it to special chars.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'id': ["bike0", "biKe10", "veh0", "veh10", "moto100"]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["id"] = df["id"].str.replace(r"[a-z]","", case=False)
print(df)
```