# Removing all non-numeric values from a string

Tags: python-3.x

The task is to return all numbers in a string, excluding all letters. My current is such as:

```
def get_digits(cs: str) -> str:
   

    str1 = ''
    for c in cs:
        if c.isdigit():
            a = str1.join(c)

        

    return a
```

For example, when **get_digits("a1b2c3")** is entered, the desired output is 123. Currently the returned result is '3'. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: you have 2 way to do it ,1. save the digital char in a list then use join
2. concatenate string each time u find

Comment: define `a = ''` repalce `a = str1.join(c) ` by `a += c`

Answer (score 1):

Regex is your better option here, if you want to remove all non-digit, you can do something like

```py
>>> cs = "a1b2c3"
>>> re.sub('\D', '', cs)
'123'
```

But you can do better by extracting directly numbers in a list

```py
>>> cs = "a1b24c3"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', cs)
['1', '24', '3']
```

both solutions works, it depends of your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning '3' because you are overwriting the 'a' variable each time the iteration of the for loop ends
You can just concatenate each result number to the str1 variable:

```
def get_digits(cs: str) -> str:
       

    str1 = ''
    for c in cs:
        if c.isdigit():
            str1 += c
            # str1 += c it's the same as str1 = str1 + c

        

    return str1
```

This will return your desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using only string related functions, like below:

```
input_str = "a1b2c3"

numbers = ''.join((ch if ch in '0123456789' else ' ') for ch in input_str)
numbers_list = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]

print(numbers_list)
```