# How can we extract a next numeric value to a string in python

Tags: python, string

There is a need that I have a taken a output in a string such as string is
"Initial: [818 v1] any other string or words here" and here I want to take 818 from this string. This 818 can change so can't hard code it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: why not `1` its also a numeric value

Comment: what are the exact rules to select the 818? Can you provide more examples? What is fixed and variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
s = "Initial: [818 v1] any other string or words here"

import re
p = re.findall(r'\d+',s)
print(p)
```

OUTPUT

```py
['818','1']
```

But if you only want the number which has more than 1 character Then

```py
s = "Initial: [818 v1] any other string or words here"

import re
p = re.findall(r'\d+',s)
p = list(filter(lambda e:len(e)-1,p))
print(p)
```

OUTPUT:

```py
['818']
```

After OP wants another question answer.

```py
string = 'Abc 1 String Xyz 3 try new 4'

string_lst = string.split()

def func(lst,e):
    if not lst[e].isdigit():
        try:
            int(lst[e+1])
        except IndexError:
            return lst[e]
        except ValueError:
            return False
        else:
            return lst[e]
    return lst[e]

lst = [func(string_lst,a) for a in range(len(string_lst))]

string_list = list(filter(lambda e:e,lst))

string_dict = {string_list[a]:int(string_list[a+1]) for a in range(0,len(string_list),2)}
print(string_dict)
```

Or you can try this way

```py
import re

s = 'Abc 1 String Xyz 3 try new 4'

matches = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*(\d+)?', s)
result = {key: int(value) for key, value in matches if value}

print(result)
```

#### OUTPUT

```
{'Abc': 1, 'Xyz': 3, 'new': 4}
```

Comment: I don't think the 1 is wanted

Comment: @mozway check now.

Comment: I don't think I'd do it this way, you can avoid selecting the 1 in the first place, but the question is too ambiguous at the moment to really know what is expected

Comment: Yes thanks, it answers the question. I can use RE to extract all numeric value and then use the list to find my useable value.

Comment: @SharimIqbal Thanks! Also can you tell like we I have some specific string and in front of them I have different numeric value, how can we extract that For ex: 
"Initial: [818 v1] any other string or words here Abc 1 String 2 Xyz 3" 
So I need a output like {"Abc": 1, "String": 2, "Xyz": 3}

Comment: @SumitSomani Check now.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I think this will be kind of hard coded right, I think may be question was confusing, but let me clarify, it is not necessary that after each string there will be numeric value, there may or may not be, it can be string = 'Abc 1 String Xyz 3 try new 4' so here I need it like {"Abc": 1, "Xyz": 3, "new":4}

Comment: @SumitSomani Wait a minute

Comment: @SumitSomani I know it will take more than a minute But can you check now.