# Split python string in a specific way

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a string like `a = 'This is an example string that has a code !3377! this is the code I want to extract'`.

How can I extract `3377` from this string, i.e., the part surrounded by `!`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing what you are looking for. But the most optimal way of doing it would be by using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

For example, in the case you gave:

```py
import re


def subtract_code_from(sentence: str) -> str:
    m = re.search(r'\w?!(\d+)!\w?', sentence)
    return m.group(0)
```

Keep in mind that what I've done is a very quick and loose solution I implemented in five minutes. I don't know what other types of particular cases you could encounter for each sentence. So it is your job to implement the proper regex to match all the cases.

I encourage you to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). And you can use [this website](https://regex101.com/) to build your regexes.

Good luck.