# Select the previous date from a list nearest to today's date

Tags: python, date

I have a list of dates in a .csv and I would like to fetch a date nearest to today's date. How do I achieve that? Issue is in the list, Sat, Sun and holidays are omitted. Can anyone please help?

[image]

I don't know how to read data from csv and get the previous date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to get this done in python

Answer (score 0):

Since .csv is a text file, you can open it with notepad.exe.
Then just do some text parsing.
About csv file format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values.

This code from [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python) should work to extract numbers form the string.

```
[int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', "he33llo 42 I'm a 32 string 30")]
result: [42, 32, 30]
```