# TTK Enty validation issue

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry, data-entry

I am writing my very first GUI app with Py and Tkinter (Ttkinter). I want to be sure that the user can write only digits, "," and "." in the entries field. So far I did this but I have a couple of issues:

1. I am not able to make it accept "," and ".";
2. Using this method I can't use the clean functions that I wrote to clean the entries widget.

```py
#Validation function
def dig_check(input):
    if input.isdigit():
        print(input)
        return True
    
    else:
        print(input)
        return False

#Clean function
def clean_calc():
    r_top_entry.delete(0,END)
    r_bot_entry.delete(0,END)
    p_thick_entry.delete(0,END)
    b_angle_deg_entry.delete(0,END)
    b_angle_m_entry.delete(0,END)
    b_angle_s_entry.delete(0,END)
    b_height_entry.delete(0,END)

    De_label.config(text="-")
    Dm_label.config(text="-")
    Di_label.config(text="-")
    de_label.config(text="-")
    dm_label.config(text="-")
    di_label.config(text="-")

    deg_value.config(text="-")
    min_value.config(text="-")
    sec_value.config(text="-")

#Entry widget example
r_top_entry = ttk.Entry(blank_frame, width=10, validate="key", validatecommand=(root.register(dig_check),"%P"))
```

Can someone help me and explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"I am not able to make it accept "," and ".";"_ you're explicitly allowing only digits. Have you tried modifying your validation function to accept all of the characters you want it to accept?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify your validator to accept the other characters

```Python
def dig_check(usr_input):
    # accept digits, '.', ',', or empty values
    char = usr_input[-1]  # get the latest character added to the Entry
    if char.isdigit() or char in '.,' or char == '':
        return True
    return False
```

It's good to accept empty values as well so the user can delete the contents of the `Entry`. You'll need to check for these after the fact, but if you don't catch them here your `Entry` will always have to have *some* value, which is probably not what you want.

Note that this will also permit multiple consecutive '.' and ',' characters, and won't dictate where those characters are allowed. For something more stringent, you'll probably want to look at RegEx.

Also, I've changed `input` to `usr_input` since `input` is a reserved word (it's a function)

---

If you want to be more prescribed in your validation (and generally, you should!), you can do something like this:

```
import re


def dig_check(usr_input):
    pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+(?:,?\d*)*.?\d*$|^$')
    if re.search(pattern, user_input):
        return True
    return False
```

Bear in mind that the RegEx pattern here isn't exhaustive, and can allow for things like multiple consecutive commas...I'm just demonstrating a point!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!! This fixed the 2nd point but not the 1st, I am still not able to use ".," char :(

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm confused - there is no call to `get()` here

Comment: @JRiggles: my apologies. I'm not sure why I thought `get` was there. I guess I saw the comment "get the latest character" and didn't look at the code.

Comment: @No worries! Can I have my rep back? ;)

Comment: @JRiggles you'll have to edit the question before I can change my vote. The edit doesn't have to be significant.

Comment: @BryanOakley Interesting, I don't think I knew that was a feature. Edited! I appreciate your input, as ever.