Extract float values from string in Python
I have a line as below and I need to extra the float values for SW A_done: and SW B_done:.
line = SW A_done:    191168 SW B_done:     27720

I tried line.split(' ' ), and then look for value after A_done: but it seems to show lot of null values when SW A_done value is 0 and is not always next value after A_done, B_done.
line.split(' ' ) :
['SW', 'A_done:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', 'SW', 'B_done:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0'] After trying with line.split( ' ' )

How can I extract the float values separately in above line ?

That's a case where a regex would be appropriate? Show what code you have tried and the cases where it fails.

['SW', 'A_done:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', 'SW', 'B_done:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0'] After trying with line.split( '  ' ).

line.split(' ') is the only thing you've tried…? Surely you need a little more post-processing afterwards…?

Thats the only thing I knew as I am new to Python. Can you help me if you can ?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4289331/476 and the aforelinked http://regular-expressions.info.

For starters, you need line.split(), not line.split(' ').
